# How possible that an memory address also have another memory address ?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I have stored the address of a integer variable in a pointer and then store the address of that previous into another pointer.I am not able to understand how it actually works.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int  var;
    int  *ptr;
    int  **pptr;

    var = 30;

    /* take the address of var */
    ptr = &var;

   /* take the address of ptr using address of operator & */
    pptr = &ptr;

    /* take the value using pptr */
    printf("Value of var = %d\n", var );
    printf("Value available at ptr = %d\n", ptr );
    printf("Value available at pptr = %d\n", pptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you not able to understand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a pointer also have any address or memory allocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991075/does-a-pointer-also-have-any-address-or-memory-allocation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `&ptr` you get the address of the variable `ptr` is stored.

So you have a pointer `pptr` which points at `ptr` which in turn point at `var`. Like this:

```
+------+     +-----+     +-----+
| pptr | --> | ptr | --> | var |
+------+     +-----+     +-----+
```

---

On a side-note, don't use the `"%d"` format to print pointers. Use `"%p"` instead, and then cast the pointers to `void *`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `var` is stored at the memory address 0x12345678, `ptr` at the address 0x23456789 and `pptr` at the address 0x34567890.

When you do

```
var = 30;
```

you store 30 in the value of var (at the address of var, `0x12345678`)

When you do

```
ptr = &var;
```

you store the address of var in the value of ptr.
When you do

```
pptr = &ptr;
```

you store the address of ptr in the value of pptr.

The memory looks like this

```
Address       Value stored
...
0x12345678    30
...
0x23456789    0x12345678
...
0x34567890    0x23456789
```

If you try to print `pptr`, it will show `0x23456789`
If you try to print `*pptr`, it will show the value at the address corresponding to the value of `pptr`, `012345678`
And if you try to print `**pptr`, it will show the value at the address corresponding to the value at the address corresponding to the value of `pptr`, `30`

Answer (score 1):

This ASCII art will help you to understand

```
       pptr                ptr                 var       

   +----------+        +----------+        +-----------+
   |          |        |          |        |           |
   | 0x67890  +------> |  0x12345 +------> |    30     |
   |          |        |          |        |           |
   +----------+        +----------+        +-----------+
     0xABCDE             0x67890              0x12345
```