# Where can I learn more about pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I do not understand pointers. Where can I learn more about them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Richard Buckland](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=richard+buckland&search_type=&aq=f)'s [lecture about pointers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw) is highly recommendable.

Comment: have you guys actually watched this? Good gosh, the dude us a smooth talker but he hasn't programmed in his whole life... he just knows the material by heart... wow.

Comment: My favorite is at 14.55, when he talks about memory addresses and dereferencing... do you think he's ever done this before in a real program?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to understand pointers is to write assembly, I found.

Comment: +1 - there's quite a bit of truth to this.  Pointers are dead simple if you understand what's going on behind the scenes.  I learned assembly on a Cosmac and later a BBC micro some years before I first touched C.  With that grounding pointers are a no-brainer.

Comment: Actually, technically I learned machine code on a Cosmac - it didn't have an assembler.

Comment: Thelimitations of any assembler language force you to deal with addresses all the time and so you simply *have* to become comfortable with them to do anything whatsoever.  Every higher-level language abstracts away from this to some degree, C probably least of all.  This is one of the reasons C is often referred to as a "structured assembler".

Comment: ps: The assembly you'll have easiest access to - x86, is probably the worst to begin learning. Every compiler out there uses quite messy syntax and the CISC instructions are pretty odd to my mind. 
My first assembly that I got involved in to any real degree was ARM (using this[1] tool -- not sure how appropriate it is for home nistallation/use). I would really recommend ARM, PIC, MIPS over x86. I'm not aware of any specially designed assembly "teaching" language ala Pascal. Maybe try the From Nand to Tetris[2]?

[1]http://brej.org/kmd/ 
[2]http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/

Comment: Pod, that 2nd link you gave looks really good, can't wait to try it out.

Comment: I've not tried it myself (I found out about it after 3 years in a Computer Engineering degree -- which essentially does the exact same thing, just in more detail). I just saw a video of a presentation by the guy. It looked great.

Answer (score 3):

try http://home.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Answer (score 0):

I personally like the quite straightforward [cplusplus.com tutorial on pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/).

Answer (score 0):

My C language bible is "C-The complete Reference" by Schildt.  Chapter 5 is all about pointers.

If you just think of the pointer as being the address of something - like the address in a letter telling you how to find the house - then you will be most of the way there.

Comment: Dont Read His Books. They Are not correct . Please See ACCU review of the book https://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=214

Comment: https://accu.org/index.php?module=bookreviews&func=search&rid=214

Answer (score 0):

Deitel & Deitel C how to program
[C++ version of the book preview on Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=HhGB8fOiUy8C&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers on C (Paperback)
by Kenneth Reek (Author)

[http://www.amazon.com/Pointers-C-Kenneth-Reek/dp/0673999866](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0673999866)

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of great references suggested.  I'd just like to add one thing:

*Play with them!*

Once you understand them on the theoretical level from the books, articles, lectures, videos above then you should set yourself to some task that that will allow you to make mistakes, find those mistakes and fix mistakes.

Think about implementing something like a linked list (double or singly linked), binary tree, or similar data structure.  Then write some code to insert and remove values from your structure.  In completing the task you'll definitely feel more comfortable with them, and get some experience debugging pointer problems.