# Reinitializing pointer previously 'free'd

Tags: cs50

I'm currently working on CS50's Lab 4 - Volume.  I have the following code and I'm wondering if it's okay to use the same pointer name in two separate places after calling free on it.

```
 //Initialize tmp pointer and copy header bytes from input to output file
uint8_t *tmp = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
if (*tmp == NULL)
{
    printf("Mem_ERR_2\n");
    return 2;
}

for (int b = 0; b < 44; b++)
{
    *tmp = fgetc(*input);
    *output = fputc(*tmp);
    printf("H_BYTE = %i\n", b++);
}

free(*tmp);
```

I have  `*tmp` initialized, dereferenced it, and now I'm calling free on it.  After this I want to create a second `*tmp` pointer for a different part of code.  My question is, it it good practice, or even syntactically okay to initialize `uint16_t *tmp` for a second pointer?  Or should I change them to `*tmp1` and `*tmp2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practices to avoid problems with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432963/best-practices-to-avoid-problems-with-pointers)

Comment: Syntactically I'd assume not (differing types, redeclaration of a variable, etc.), but as far as "good practice" I'd be in the "no" camp. Try thinking of a more relevant variable name than `tmp`.

Comment: Ok, I sort of was thinking that, but I wanted to get some opinions.  As far as the linked post, I didn't really see what I was looking for specifically, but I didn't dig through everything.  I will definitely look through that post because there looks like some good info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, the line `*tmp == NULL` is a bug. If `malloc` fails and returns `NULL`, then evaluating the expression `*tmp` will cause a segmentation fault. Instead, try `tmp == NULL`. This also means that `free(*tmp)` is a bug - it should be `free(tmp)` instead.

Now, to answer your question: It is perfectly fine to reassign a pointer variable after it has been freed. For example, the following is perfectly valid:

```
int * ptr = malloc(16);
free(ptr);

int x = 5;
ptr = &x;

ptr = malloc(16);
free(ptr);
```