# C Pointers - Good Tutorials

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Was just wondering if anyone could "point me"  to a good tutorial on pointers

Would be very greatful

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best start is Kernighan and Ritchie book of "Programming in C".

Answer (score 1):

There is always [Pointer Fun with Binky](http://www.cs.stanford.edu/cslibrary/PointerFunCBig.avi), produced by Stanford.

Answer (score 0):

Well, http://pweb.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/cpoint.htm seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I like [C for smarties](http://elf.torek.net/torek/c/) a lot.  It deals with many of the issues people face with pointers, is written by someone who knows C very well, and to paraphrase Einstein, doesn't simplify things more than they need to be.  In particular, you should read "[Are pointers numbers?](http://elf.torek.net/torek/c/numbers2.html)", and "[More on arrays and pointers](http://elf.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html)" from the website.

Also, see [`comp.lang.c` FAQ](http://c-faq.com/), sections [4](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html), [5](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html), [6](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html), and [7](http://c-faq.com/malloc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

While not related *only* to pointers, **Defensive Programming** is something that should definitely read up on and practice.It greatly reduces the number of mistakes that a programmer can mak

Here's a couple of nice links:

- Dr Dobbs - http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401915
- Defensive C Programming - http://geofftop.com/Defensive_C_Programming.html

Answer (score 0):

Read *The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie; it is excellent.