# Very Basic C Question

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone check my understanding and correct me if i am wrong?

```
int p = 5; //create an int holding 5
int *ptr; //create a pointer that can point to an int
*ptr = &p; // not sure - does this mean that my pointer now points to memory address   five, or that the memory address my pointer points at contains 5?
```

Sorry for the basic question - i have an assignmnet soon that requires the use of pointers and i really want to crack the basics before its set.

Comment: You might want to read this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome

Comment: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/mimic.html

Comment: BTW, bonus points for starting out using 
int *ptr 
rather than 
int* ptr :)

Comment: Can we rename this question to something more helpful for posterity?

Answer (score 5):

Almost there - change it to:

```
int p = 5; // create an int holding 5
int *ptr; // create a pointer that can point to an int
ptr = &p; // ptr now points at p
```

Comment: Then (and this is the point of pointers), you can do `*ptr = 6;`. The `*ptr` means "the thing pointed to by ptr", so this changes the value of `p` to 6, just as if you'd done `p = 6`.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is wrong. ptr is not initialized. Assigning to `*ptr` creates a memory violation most likely. You can't assign an `int*` (which `&p` is) to an `int` (which `*ptr` is).

Correct is:

```
ptr = &p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ptr` now points to the memory address that has `5` stored in it.

Also, I don't believe that code compiles.  You probably want:

```
int p = 5; //create an int holding 5
int *ptr; //create a pointer that can point to an int
ptr = &p; // not sure - does this mean that my pointer now points to memory address   five, or that the memory address my pointer points at contains 5?
```

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is, basically, an address.  Think about a pointer as an address label, and the value as the actual house.  You can use the label to *find* the house, but the label *isn't* a house.

```
int *ptr; // declares a pointer to an int
```

So ptr is, essentially, a memory address.  (It's possible that the C spec doesn't actually specify that it's an address, but bear with me).

```
int i = 5; // create a local int.
```

Declares an integer on the stack, and sets the value of it to 5.  The address of i is somewhere in the stack space.

Let's look at one intermediate step before we go on.  This probably wouldn't compile, and if it did, wouldn't actually *do* anything.

```
&i;
```

What this expression does is return the address of the variable i.  It's the location of i in memory - the *address* of an integer.

And one last one...

```
*ptr;
```

Again, this probably wouldn't actually do anything, it's just an expression.  But, what it does is dereference the pointer - it refers to the actual int located at the address contained in ptr.

Okay, so let's take a look at a few things that we can do.

```
ptr = i;
```

This doesn't do anything, at least anything we want to do.  Probably won't compile, but I haven't checked it out.  It doesn't do anything because it assigns an integer to the *address* of an integer.  That's like sending a box through the post office to an address label - you actually want it to go to the house!

```
i = ptr;
```

Okay, this is the same thing as the last one, but in reverse.  Following our analogy, this is trying to turn a house into a label!

```
*ptr = i;
```

Here we've dereferenced the pointer, and assigned the value of i to it.  Dereferencing a pointer is essentially like using the label to drive to the house.  Once we're there, we can do things to the actual house.  This works because a dereferenced int pointer is an int, and an int is also an int.

```
ptr = &i;
```

This works too.  &i basically makes a new label for the house 'i'.  Since we have a pointer on both sides, we can assign one to the other.  This is basically copying the address label for i to the address label called ptr.

```
*ptr = &i;
```

This doesn't make sense.  We've started with two different things, and converted each into the other!  Now we're trying to assign a label to a house, whereas before we were assigning a house to an address label.

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
ptr = &p; // set ptr to point to the location holding p
```

Answer (score 0):

Others already explained how to fix your code. For understanding, let me tell you what your *wrong* line does:

```
*ptr = &p;
```

`*ptr` *dereferences* the pointer, i.e., `*ptr = ...` assigns something into the memory slot to which `ptr` is pointing. Since `ptr` has not been initialized, it points to some unknown location in memory and `*ptr = ...` will probably fail with a `Segmentation Fault` or something similar.

Since `ptr` is a pointer to `int`, the right-hand side of `*ptr = ...` expects an int as well, but you pass to it the *address of an int* (`&p`), which results in a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your immediate question (which others have already done), but I would recommend reading the [section on pointers](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=ptrs) from the c-faq.

Lot's of good info.

Answer (score 0):

int a=5;

declare the pointer type which is your storing

int *ptr;

assign address of variable to the pointer

ptr=&a;