# question on c pointers

Tags: c, pointers

This is just a doubt which came into my mind

here is the code shown below

```
          main()
          {
                  int *p,*q;
                  int a =20;
                  p = q;
                  p = &a;
                  free(p);
                  printf("The values of p and q are %d and %d\n",*p,*q);
           }
```

My doubt is if we free the pointer p,the memory allocated for this pointer gets deallocated and is returned to the free pool of memory and so in this case since q is also pointing to p,dereferencing q should give error as per my understanding.Am i right in telling that??
i had run this program in dev C++ compiler and to my surprise it is showing the values for both the pointers.
Do we call the pointer q as the dangling pointer in this case?

thanks a lot in advance
Maddy

Comment: don't do that.  `free()` is for memory allocated with `malloc()` (and its friends)

Comment: you will get a segmentation fault when you run in gcc

Comment: It segfaults as expected using glibc. I've posted an illustration of why (via Valgrind) to show why.

Answer (score 4):

Attempting to free `p` here invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - you're only allowed to free what you malloc (or calloc, or realloc, or strdup). In this case, you're free-ing a pointer to a stack variable, `a`, which is not allowed.

The same applies to dereferencing `*q` - the value in `q` is uninitialized, so dereferencing it causes undefined behavior as well. Strictly speaking, `p = q` is undefined* as well, but in practice simply copying the value of an uninitialized variable tends not to cause too much of a problem in and of itself (just don't expect the value to be meaningful).

When you invoke undefined behavior, **anything** can happen - this includes, but is not limited to:

- Crashing right away
- Crashing later in some unrelated code
- Corrupting some data without crashing
- Corrupting some data on disk that you thought was safe
- Contacting your backup server and corrupting the backups too
- Allowing the hacker who triggered the bug control over your computer
- [Summoning demons through your nasal passages](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)
- Any combination of the above
- On occasion, nothing at all.

The compiler is **not** required to give any sort of helpful error message, although it *may* do so in some cases.

In short, don't do it, but don't expect it to break in any one particular way if you do. These kinds of things have a funny way of breaking in a way that looks like bugs in a completely different part of your code.

* - per C99 6.2.6.1, if the C implementation has trap representations for pointer types, it is possible for the unspecified initial value for a variable to be a trap representation, at which point reading it via the `q` lvalue invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

How can you free memory from the stack?

Does not compute!

Comment: @leppie...Free should actually free the memory pointed by p .So when u derefernce q,it should give error right?Please coirrect me if i am wrong

Comment: @Maddy: `free` only frees memory allocated by `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about pointers and understand them better. [Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

```
p = q
```

`q` is an uninitialized pointer, you are assigning `p` to point to the same unspecified memory zone.

```
p = &a;
```

This is okay, now `p` contains the address of `a` but `q` remains uninitialized

```
free(p);
```

`a` is stored in the stack, not the heap. Could could have done this with :

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int)); // allocates memory and stores location
*a = 20;                      // modifies allocated memory
p = a;                        // have a second pointer to the same zone
free(p);                      // frees the allocated memory: now dereferencing either p or a is a sin.
```

Comment: if i change the order like first p = &a;

Comment: then when you say `p = q` you assign p, not q. `q` will never be valid in your code if you do not initialize it with `q = something`.

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `free()` on a pointer to a stack-allocated memory and that's undefined behavior, don't ever do that. Only call `free()` on pointers obtained from `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

a is an automatic variable, and applyinf free(p) where p=&a is an error, that you probably face up as soon you malloc other memory, since you mark as a free block memory that is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to `free` memory that was not acquired with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` leads to UNDEFINED RESULTS. Sometimes it does something stupid like continuing to run and giving you silly results. Somtimes it does something more useful:

```
$ ./a.out
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff8393bd5c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x774b6)[0x7f7a30bc04b6]
./a.out[0x400526]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfe)[0x7f7a30b67d8e]
./a.out[0x400439]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 675233                             /tmp/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:03 675233                             /tmp/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:03 675233                             /tmp/a.out
00f04000-00f25000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f7a30933000-7f7a30948000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 228559                     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f7a30948000-7f7a30b47000 ---p 00015000 08:03 228559                     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f7a30b47000-7f7a30b48000 r--p 00014000 08:03 228559                     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f7a30b48000-7f7a30b49000 rw-p 00015000 08:03 228559                     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f7a30b49000-7f7a30cc3000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 228962                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f7a30cc3000-7f7a30ec2000 ---p 0017a000 08:03 228962                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f7a30ec2000-7f7a30ec6000 r--p 00179000 08:03 228962                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f7a30ec6000-7f7a30ec7000 rw-p 0017d000 08:03 228962                     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so
7f7a30ec7000-7f7a30ecc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                      
7f7a30ecc000-7f7a30eec000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 228501                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f7a310cc000-7f7a310cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f7a310ea000-7f7a310ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                      
7f7a310ec000-7f7a310ed000 r--p 00020000 08:03 228501                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f7a310ed000-7f7a310ee000 rw-p 00021000 08:03 228501                     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7f7a310ee000-7f7a310ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                      
7fff8391d000-7fff8393e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff839df000-7fff839e0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

My C library helpfully gives me the address that failed, and *very* helpfully dumps the memory map (which is new to me! thanks!) which lets me see quickly that the address is on the stack.

Comment: Incidentally, a very rough search of an old copy of the cve.mitre.org database shows something like 60 vulnerabilities in software due to use-after-free and double-free bugs, and perhaps another 4 free(NULL) bugs leading to vulnerabilities. Please make sure you understand the correct use of `malloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the exact behavior that I expected when run through Valgrind:

```
==8839== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==8839==    at 0x4024836: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
==8839==    by 0x8048440: main (boom.c:10)
==8839==  Address 0xbe9a5164 is on thread 1's stack
```

I did it because I was curious, as several were reporting the same behavior.

The address of `p` (as dereferenced by `free()`) is what is known as a dangling pointer, thus any operation on it is undefined. I compiled without optimization (-O0) and with debugging symbols (-g) to produce a better illustration, but it blows up no matter what.

Running the program normally just produces a segmentation fault, as expected. The program actually completes when profiled under valgrind (additional complaints when `printf()` also dereferences the explosive pointer):

```
==8839== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==8839==    at 0x8048445: main (boom.c:11)
==8839==
The values of p and q are 20 and 459916161
==8839==
==8839== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8839==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8839==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 1 frees, 0 bytes allocated
```

But only because Valgrind is catching the SEGV.

Undefined behavior is just that, undefined. It is one of the leading causes of the dreaded "wow, works on my machine!" bug :)