# Why does new operator throw an error here?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, new-operator, heap-memory

class-name object-name = new constructor-name() throws an error (line 16 of code)
From this I can infer that new returns a pointer, is my conclusion correct? Also if the new doesn't work on this does that mean that the object someObject is allocated on the stack and not heap? What if I want to create an object on the heap?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class someClass
{
        public:
                int x;
                someClass()
                {
                        x=6;
                }
};
int main()
{
        someClass someObject;
        someClass *pointerObject;
        someObject = new someClass(); //This line throws error
        pointerObject = new someClass();
        cout<<someObject.x<<endl<<pointerObject->x;
        return 0;
}
```

p.s: I know the question is vague but I couldn't put it in better words, I apologize for inconvenience caused.

Comment: This code is not compiled, it should be `someClass* someObject;`

Comment: `someObject` is already an object. This isn't Java or C#.

Comment: In Java or C# you use new to create objects. In C++ you only rarely do this, normally you create objects just by declaring them. `someClass someObject;` creates an object, no need for `new`.

Comment: That line isn't "throwing an error" per se. That has a very specific, technical meaning in C++. Instead, it's causing a compiler error because it's not legal C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line of `main`

```
someClass someObject;
```

is already called default constructor without parameters.
`new` function returns a pointer to an object and next you trying to assign pointer to an object.

You may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372707/in-c-whats-the-difference-between-an-object-and-a-pointer-to-an-object) some explaining of objects and pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Because `new` returns `pointer`, which you are trying to assign to object. C++ is not C#!