# What is different between *variable and variable* in c?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a question I would appreciate it if you could clarify it.
I am new to c and I encountered a part of the code in c which is as follows

```
#include <List.h>
LIST<P1*> p1
```

where the p1 is

```
class P1
  {
     public:

P1(int i, VECTOR xi);
```

Could you please tell me what `p1*` means in  `LIST<P1*>`?

Is that a pointer?

Comment: To begin with, you're programming in ***C++*** and not C.

Comment: And `P1*` in this context means "pointer to a P1 object". So `LIST<P1*>` is a list (I assume) of pointers to `P1` objects.

Comment: Also, `P1` isn't a variable, it's a type

Comment: @ForceBru could you please tell me" <p1*>& " means?

Comment: @babaksinichi, this piece by itself probably doesn't mean anything

Comment: @ForceBru I meant something like this " <p1*>&  p2 ", could you please tell me what it means?

Comment: @babaksinichi, this doesn't mean anything. `LIST<P1*>& p2` would mean that the symbol `p2` is a reference to data of type `LIST<P1*>`.

Comment: @ ForceBru thanks, do you know the reference that explains these things?

Comment: @babaksinichi any [decent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) would cover this.

Answer (score 0):

like comments said, "P1*" is a pointer to an object of type "P1".

On the other hand " * p1" is an indirection (telling the compiler that it is an adress) on the content of the pointer p1;

```
P1* pp1;
P1 p1;
```

returning *pp1 is like returning p1;

returning pp1 return the adress of the pointed object.

cf : [C++ - *p vs &p vs p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661293/c-p-vs-p-vs-p)

Comment: to try and clarify P1* pp1 contains an adress, *pp1 return the object at the adress in pp1, pp1 return the adress; thats the difference.

Comment: could you please tell me what <p1*>& means too? thanks