# Why are Pointers in Swap Function not Changing values in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, swap

I'm trying to swap two floats using pointers ,

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(float* p, float* q);


int main() {
    double num1,num2;
    printf("Please write 2 numbers ");
    scanf("%lf %lf",&num1 , &num2);
    swap(&num1,&num2);
    printf("\nnum1 is  : %.2lf \n",num1);
    printf("num2 is  : %.2lf \n",num2);

    return 0;
}

void swap(float* p, float* q){
    float a;
    a=*p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=a;

}
```

My issues :

1. The code doesn't swap
2. The pointers in the swap function show value 0 for the pointer of the address I'm sending .

For example - input 99 22 -> gives me 0 :

[Using Debugger I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERLVf.png)

I don't get why I'm getting that , if [according to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334576/18475383) I have an address
that I sent (let's assume I sent 00001 ) then a pointer to that address would be my value (99 in this example ) but I get 0 ...

**I'd appreciate any help !**

Comment: You are mixing double and float here. Even worse, pointers to them. This is definitely not ok. Please try again with either all doubles or all floats.

Comment: Every self-respecting C or C++ compiler will refuse to compile this. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You are passing pointers to `double` to a swap function that expects its arguments to be pointers to `float`.  If your compiler is not complaining about that then find the dial to turn up the warnings, or get a better compiler.  With that mismatch, the execution of `swap()` has undefined behavior, which could certainly manifest with the symptoms you describe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No, with default settings, they will just issue warnings.

Comment: @eric - the result from gcc with default settings: `t.C:10:10: error: cannot convert ‘double*’ to ‘float*’` --  a little bit more than just a warning. No soup for you.

Comment: on my side `gcc -Wall -g` throw warnings but compile without error...

Comment: only warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` using [gcc 12.1](https://godbolt.org/z/KGbG3GY7M) and [clang 14.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/eTjrE5sh6)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [GCC 12.1 with no switches produces only warnings.](https://godbolt.org/z/YEdoor8Gj)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: As C++, GCC issues an error rather than a warning.

Comment: Most important : never ignore compiler warnings : try to understand what is wrong. Sometimes warning may not be harmful but never rely on luck.

Comment: `gcc (GCC) 12.1.1 20220507 (Red Hat 12.1.1-1)` results in an error, @EricPostpischil

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Read all the comments.

Comment: I appreciate the help , I didn't catch that and thought it was something more complicated with pointers , Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by comments, the problem is that your swap function takes `float` pointers while you are using `double` variables.

Since `float` type is used to describe floating point value over 4 bytes (32 bits) and the `double` type describes floating point value over 8 bytes (64 bits), when you pass `double` pointers to a function that treat them as `float` type, the values are wrongly assigned (over 4 bytes instead of 8 bytes) from one memory area to another.

The half of bits of a `double` does not make a **valid corresponding** `float`.

Comment: Well, actually it does. Probably not the right one, though. :)

Comment: @PhilMasteG confusing indeed :) I edited answer to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Changed to float and it worked ( and changed the scanf to %f) , Thanks !