# what does compare to string here mean?

Tags: c

I see a very interesting code to reverse a string,
but I don't understand here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Reverse(char *s);

int main()
{
    char *s=NULL;
    s=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
    gets(s);
    Reverse(s);
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}

void Reverse(char *s)
{
    char *end=s;
    char tmp;
    if (s)
    {
        while (*end)   
        {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (s<end)  ??
        {
            tmp=*s;
            *s++=*end;
            *end--=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

I see the this program tries to work on the same string by using end=s to change both string at the same time, but what does '*' line : `while(s<end)`  here mean?

I use gdb and find that when we input `asdfgh`, when *s is fdsa and *end is fds, this is no longer true, how this line controls the program?

I just want to know what '??' line mean..

Thanks a lot !

Comment: No, this code has undefined behaviour.  You're only allocating enough space to hold a pointer.

Comment: When you format code like this, God kills a kitten.

Comment: `s` and `end` are pointers. Their values are not things like "asdfg" or "fds"; their values are things like 0xdeadbeef or 0x424242.

Comment: 1. What 2 same functions are doing here? --- 2. " when we input asdfgh, when s is fdsa and end is fds" - senseless and ununderstandable sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C are terminated by the `\0` character, which has the integer value `0`. As such it is a false value.

By using `while(*end)` you check whether `end` is pointing on the termination character of the given string. If it isn't pointing on the end, you move it further (`++end`). To ensure that the pointer is valid you move the "cursor" backward after this.

`while(s < end)` will now move check whether `s` is further forwarded than `end`. If not, then you'll swap the value of both "cursor". `end` will move toward `s` and vice versa. This way you're going to reverse the string.

You're debugging output is a result of gdbs interpretation. It interpreds `end` as a *string*, not a single character. Have a look at `*end` while debugging.

Note that your `malloc` is completely wrong. You have to allocate enough memory for the string, for example `s = malloc(500*sizeof(char));`. Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) instead, where you can specify the maximum number of characters to be read. Don't forget to free all memory you allocate:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 500

void Reverse(char *s);

int main()
{
    char* s = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    fgets(s,BUFFER_SIZE,stdin);
    Reverse(s);
    puts(s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}

void Reverse(char *s)
{
    char* end=s;
    char tmp;
    if(s)
    {
        while (*end)
        {
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (s<end)
        {
            tmp=*s;
            *s++=*end;
            *end--=tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I see, but what actually compares s and end here? I mean compare them as they are string or their position value or sth else?

Comment: They compare... well, you could interpret this as "position". You could access the second character of a string by using `s[1]` or `*(s+1)`. Pointer which operate on the same object are comparable, as `end>s` is equivalent to `end-s>0` and well defined for such pointers. Pointers are basically adresses (`0x0000300`,`0x0000304`,...). `malloc` will return a block of continuous memory starting at `s = 0x10`. `end` could be something like `end = 0x80`. `s<end` will compare these addresses, not the value saved on them (god, this is hard to explain), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/.

Answer (score 0):

s and end are char pointer so the test (s < end) is true until the s pointer doesn't become greater than then end pointer.

### Example

Assume that you want to reverse the string "hello" stored at the address 0x0000, ad the start of the function you have:

s = 0x0000
  end = 0x003

now the while loop:

1. s=0x0000 e=0x0003 *s=o *e=h
2. s=0x0001 e=0x0002 *s=l *e=e
3. s=0x0002 e=0x0003 << while exit >>

Comment: why it ends at last, what it compares? Thanks !