# Understanding pointers - c

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

i am really not familiar to c and pointers, I want to understand what is going on here :

```
typedef struct {
        int q[QUEUESIZE+1];
        int first;
        int last;
        int count;
} queue;
init_queue(queue *q)
{
        q->first = 0;
        q->last = QUEUESIZE-1;
        q->count = 0;
}
```

Is that correct to think that : q->first = 0 implies that if one assign to the  '0' address some value 'val', then *(q->first) will return 'val' ?

Comment: `*(q->first)` isn't even valid code.  Can you explain your question better?

Comment: What's stopping you from getting a text book on C and spending some time learning the basics. I can't imagine that this wouldn't be spelled out in great detail anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q->first` is a short hand for `(*q).first`
The parenthesis are necessary because `.` would be evaluated before the `dereference *` and since `q` is a pointer well `q.first == NOT A VALID THING`

---

`queue aQ;

init_queue(&aQ);`

the function `init_queue` take a pointer to a `queue` not a pointer to an `int`.
The role of this function is to `initialize` all the field of the structure to be usable by other function at a latter time.

Comment: Sorry but what I don't understand is if a take an 'int' i, and I pass it in init_queue(&i), (*i).first would be equivalent as setting the value of a 'typedef struct' and assign i.first a value, no ?

Answer (score 3):

No. q->first = 0 is assigning 0 to the attribute first of queue. q is a pointer but q->first is an int.