# error, incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++

```
#include "passenger.h"
class node
{
public:
    passenger dataItem;
    node nextNode;
};
```

Why do i get a incomplete type not allowed error when trying to create a varaible whose type is the class it resides in?

Comment: Which class is this error referring to.

Comment: A class cannot cobtain itself.

Answer (score 5):

Try to follow the compilers though process.

What is `sizeof(node)`.

To fix, consider using a pointer to node.

```
class node
{
public:
    passenger dataItem;
    node * nextNode;
};
```

After seeing your code, it looks like you are from Java/C# background, which means infact, that **you do actually want pointers**, to **emulate references** from those languages.

Remember that objects are **references types** in those languages, while they are **value types** in C/C++. The difference is that `node nextNode` POINTS TO the next node in Java/C# while it IS the object itself in the case of C/C++.

*Edit*: 
Your error is caused due to the fact that when you define the member variable `nextNode`, you are still in the middle of defining `node`, thus it is *incomplete*. `node*` will work, since pointers only need a forward declaration, and are fine with incomplete types.

Similarly, it works in Java/C#, because every variable in those languages (minus C# `struct`s and Java primitives) are just pointers with some make up.

Edit: Please read up on pointers in C++ and `new`/`delete` I expect you are in for a crash or two soon.. :(. Also take a look at [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome) to start.

To summarize, to assign a pointer you do the following.

```
node a;
node b;

a.nextNode = &b; //& operator returns the address of its operand, here b
```

Comment: thats not really the issue, VS 2010 draws a red line under nextNode and says "Error: incomplete type is not allowed". I have yet to compile because of the error

Comment: Its incomplete because it is incomplete.. the `};` comes after your definition of the member variable.