# C++ Pointer Pointing to index of an Array of Objects

Tags: c++, pointers

Quick questions about pointers.
In this example:

```
  Object *O;

  Object** array = new Object*[3];

  O = array[0];
```

In this example, Does O point to the spot array[0] or the object located in the position?
For example, if that object in index 0 gets swapped to say object in spot 2, I understand that O should still have access to that object not the new one now in array[0], right?

Sorry just want to double check. Been working over a day w/o sleep & starting to question what's what at this point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct.

When doing the `O = array[0];` assignment (which is equivalent to writing `O = (*array);`) you *copy* the pointer stored in the array to your pointer variable O. Any change to the array afterwards won't change the contents of O, since it is a copy.