# structure of pointer type or a structure which is a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, structure

I am studying for exam and I came across this statement. I have read couple of books and notes and so far i have not come across this and also i dont even know what to call it so i have not able to find the answer.

Here it goes.

```
 typedef struct {
         unsigned a: 4;
         unsigned b: 4;
 } byte, *pByte;// what does *pbyte means here?

int main(){
pByte p = (pByte)x; // this is typecasting void pointer. how does it work with *pbyte
 byte temp;
 unsigned i;

 for(i = 0u; i < n; i++) {
         temp = p[i]; //again I have no idea why we suddenly have array
 }
}
```

Again if i dont know something basic......well I dont know cause im still learning :)  help me out please. thanks.

Comment: You seriously should [read this question from beginning to end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome), particularly the first answer, which is simply amazing.

Comment: I've also added [tag:c] tag since AFAIK this very concrete "problem" is same for both languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} byte, *pByte;
```

defines a structure with an alias `byte` and defines an alias `pByte` for `byte*` as well, so 
that you can use it the following way:

```
byte b;
pByte pB = &b;
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
byte b;
byte* pB = &b;
```

---

So in case you have a `void` pointer `x` (which is a bit suspicious and if it is possible you should try to avoid using `void*` at first place) and you know it points to the first element of an array of `n` structs:

```
pByte p = (pByte) x;          // casts x back to the correct type
byte temp;
```

then

```
temp = p[i];
```

is possible and equivalent to (*pointer arithmetic*) :

```
temp = *(p + i);
```

Comment: +1 short and direct. nice explanation. It should be noted that most professional C programmers do *not* like pointer-typedefs, as they tend to mask the in-your-face attention the asterisks bring to the reviewer. `Type *p;` declares a pointer, and its obvious. `TypeP p;` ? Um... They do, however, have one particular quality. `byte* pB, pC;`  does not declare two pointers, whereas `pByte pB, pC;` *does*. This isn't a substantial gain, however, since the former won't even compile if you try to use `pC` like a pointer. I.e. you'll catch that mistake at compile time (usually).

Comment: @WhozCraig: As long as the alias somehow carries the information that it is an alias for a pointer (i.e. `pByte`, `BytePtr`, etc.) I guess it's still fine. Otherwise it's a nasty stuff indeed.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It surely does. I'm just saying that once someone decides to make an alias for a pointer, he should explicitly express this fact in its name at least.