# How to use pointers for array instead of brackets

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to learn how to use pointers in C and I'm trying to get the equivalents for &input[71] and &input[i];

I have tried `if (*(input+i) - arrayEnd) == 0)` and it tells me I have an `int` vs `char *` comparison.

```
char input[72];
char *arrayEnd = &input[71];
if((&input[i] - arrayEnd) == 0)
```

Comment: As a starter array index 72 is invalid. Indexes in C start from zero. So an array with 72 elements will have index from 0-71.

Comment: Read This.. Seriously: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Comment: @NedStark Nevertheless, the index 72 is valid as long as it's not dereferenced. (Pointers pointing one past the last element of the array can be used for comparison.)

Answer (score 3):

> I have tried if (*(input+i) - arrayEnd) == 0) and it tells me I have an int vs char * comparison

Yes. You are doing an `int` vs `char *` comparison. `*(input+i)` means you are dereferencing the value at the address `(input+i)`.

> How to use pointers for array instead of brackets

Try this instead

```
if( ((input + i) - arrayEnd) == 0 )
```

Comment: @H2CO3; Read the tiltle: **How to use pointers for array instead of brackets**. I answered for this title. :)