# I want to use pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have pointer like this =>  char* str={"you","we","they"};

I want to take 'we' or "they" .how is it posible ?

can you sy something about pointer ?

Comment: This post shows little effort. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181712/how-to-use-pointers-for-array-instead-of-brackets

Comment: I want to use pointer - so use one! LMAO

Comment: `char* str=
{"you","we","they"};` won't compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you mean something like the following

```
char *str[] = { "you", "we", "they" };

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( str ) / sizeof( *str ); i++ )
{
    puts( str[i] );
}
```

Or

```
char *str[] = { "you", "we", "they" };

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( str ) / sizeof( *str ); i++ )
{
    for ( char *p = str[i]; *p != '\0'; ++p ) putc( *p );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```