# C++ lack of logic on pointer initialisation & use

Tags: c++, logic

This is not logic :

```
int *ptr = &otherInt;
```

When we do that, `ptr` gives adress of otherInt, `*ptr` gives otherInt.

But we write explicitly that (*ptr) equals adress `*ptr = &otherInt` !

Logically, `*ptr` should give the adress, and `ptr` the otherInt.

Don't you think ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it all wrong. Consider this:

```
int *ptr;
int otherInt = 10;

ptr = &otherInt; // Notice this line.
```

The asterisk is a part of the declaration, not the assignment.

Comment: Yes! That's why I prefer to write: `int* ptr;`

Comment: But that is even more confusing if you declare mutliple variables in one line...

Comment: _'if you declare mutliple variables in one line'_ This is **strongly discouraged** by most of the currently relevant c++ coding rules anyways.

Comment: So should be mallocing tiny, compilation-time constant in size buffers. Yet people do it. And in most cases forget to free it.