# c++ assign a 2D array to an Object

Tags: c++, arrays

My code pass the compiler, but I have a question about the concept of the pointer.

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int inputPuzzle[3][3];

    std::cout << "Set the puzzle: " << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            std::cin >> inputPuzzle[i][j];
        }
    }

    puzzle puzzle_1 = *new puzzle(inputPuzzle);
    puzzle_1.display();

    return 0;
}
```

puzzle.h:

```
class puzzle
{
    public:
        puzzle();
        puzzle(int [][maxCol]);
        ~puzzle();
    public:
        int puzz [maxRow][maxCol];
};
```

puzzle.cpp:

```
puzzle::puzzle(int a[][maxCol])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxCol; j++) {
            puzz[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about the statement :`puzzle puzzle_1 = *new puzzle(inputPuzzle);`

Why do I have to add "*" in front of the new object in which I want to assign a 2D array ?

Comment: Hello-o instant memory leak. Please, [read a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ to get the full deal on how to use pointers. This kind of thing has [been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome), but nowadays general conceptual questions about how to use pointers is frowned on.

Comment: Because the code is bad and wrong ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i49_SNt4yfk (by the way, this has nothing to do with your 2D array).

Comment: Ooh, `*new`, the memory leak operator, we meet again.

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek
Thanks for your help for giving me the direction!

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees Great book list! Thank you!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's why I have the question on that statement.
The Xcode suggests me to do so, and I do not know the reason.
it passed the compiler.....in a strange way..

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes That is called memory leak operator? I got a new lesson!

Comment: Compilers can tell you the quickest/nearest fix to make your code compile. They rarely know enough to read your mind and tell you how you _should_ write your program, though. They certainly don't detect memory leaks, or advise you against needless manual memory management. That's what _we're_ for (apparently)!

Answer (score 4):

You're programming C++, where `new` returns a pointer. When you use the asterisk it's the dereference operator, and basically turns a pointer into a non-pointer.

Using the dereference operator like that means that you actually *lose* the pointer created by `new`, and you can not free that allocated memory with `delete` which, of course, leads to a memory-leak.

To avoid losing the pointer, you have to declare the variable as a pointer:

```
puzzle* puzzle_1 = new puzzle(inputPuzzle);
```

Then you have to use the pointer member selector operator instead when accessing members:

```
puzzle_1->display();
```

And, to avoid leaking memory, when you're done with the pointer you must `delete` it:

```
delete puzzle_1;
```

---

However, in C++ there is seldom any need to use pointers; instead just declare it as a normal variable:

```
puzzle puzzle_1(inputPuzzle);
puzzle_1.display();
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but if `maxRow` or `maxCol` is larger than `3`, then you will read from outside the memory for the array `inputPuzzle`. This will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: or if you need (as in actually need, not just want) you should use smart pointers to take care of *most* of the handling. There are times though when you really do need to delve into the muddy waters of 'raw pointers', always favour cooking your pointers if you can, with a nice bit of pepper corn source and fried mushRAMs.

Answer (score 2):

The most important part here is the `new` keyword. It returns a **pointer** to the newly instantiated object. Check the [Dynamic memory allocation](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/) for more information and to understand when and how to use pointers, and how the `new` keyword works.

Now, we know that the `new` keyword returns a pointer, and you want to obtain an object not a pointer, hence you have to dereference your pointer.

Two correct solutions now:

```
// without pointers
puzzle puzzle_1(inputPuzzle); // initialize the object without going through a copy 
puzzle_1.display();

// with pointers
puzzle *puzzle_1 = new puzzle(inputPuzzle);
puzzle_1->display(); //notice that we used -> here as it's a pointer
// do stuffs here
delete puzzle_1; // free the memory
```

Comment: `puzzle puzzle_1(inputPuzzle);` is sufficient.

Comment: Indeed, was just using his own code so that he does not get disturbed by a change.

Comment: A change is precisely what he needs! :)

Comment: Done, added a comment that there is also a copy when using the `=`.