# In the following program add a statement in the function fun() such that address of a gets stored in j?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int *j;
    void fun(int**);
    fun(&j);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int **k){
    int a=10;
    /* Add a statement here */
}
```

In the following program add a statement in the function fun() such that address of a gets stored in j? Can someone please explain this whole program. I am not able to get this meaning of **.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome

Answer (score 0):

All you want is: `*k = &a;`

The `**` thing means it is a pointer to a pointer. I think the following diagram will make it clear. Open the image in a new tab to see it clearly.
[image]
Read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_pointer.htm).

Comment: but doesnt it mean **k=&j so, *(*k)=&j, so f j=0,&j=1 and **k=1

Comment: @user3867445: not really.  `int **k` means that `**k` is an `int`, and `*k` is an `int *` or `int` pointer.  Since we also have `int a`, we can deduce that `&a` is an `int` pointer too.  So, `*k = &a;` assigns an `int *` to an `int *`.  Now, in the calling code, we have `int *j`, so it is an `int` pointer.  Therefore, `&j` is an `int **` and can be passed to the function.  So, everything ties up.  Of course, once the function returns, the pointer stored in `j` is no longer valid because the function returned.  Fortunately, the code doesn't use the value.

Comment: @user3867445 Yes, @JonathanLeffler is absolutely correct. `**k` is not `&j` at all. Probably you are thinking that because the function goes like `fun(int **k)`. That is not true. Well, think of this situation as, "`fun` is being passed the address of an `int` pointer j in main()" and "`fun` takes a pointer-chain as argument"(this is also called multiple indirection). Maybe that will prevent you from going too visually. Different things work for different people. Keep experimenting with pointers. Pointers, though a little complicated, are very very powerful. Good Luck!