# Why do we use "&" before the integer variable when initializing a pointer that points to the integer?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I am currently learning pointers in C. I feel confused about the initialization of a pointer. I might be asking silly questions, but I just want to make sure I understand and learn things right.

So, to initialize a pointer:

```
int a = 3;
int *pointer = &a;
*pointer = 10;
```

OR

```
int a = 3;
int *pointer;
pointer = &a;
*pointer = 10;
```

So far, I knew that **" * "** declares a pointer type.

***pointer**    is the value of whatever value in the address that the pointer points to.

**&**    is the memory address of something.

I can understand 'pointer = &a' in the second case.

But, why do we set *pointer = &a in the first case above since ***pointer** represents the value in that address?

Why do we make the value in that pointer equals to the address of the variable in the first case when initializing the pointer?

Comment: Try to read this, it's relevant, if not a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/27484168/817643

Comment: The initialization `int *pointer = &a;` isn't assigning `&a` to `*pointer`.  It's assigning `&a` to `pointer`.

Comment: Where `&` is the **address of** operator. So `int *pointer = &a;` assigns the *address of `a`* to `pointer`. (a pointer is nothing more than a variable that stores the *address of* something else as its value...)

Comment: @StoryTeller. Thanks so much. That's exactly what I have been looking for!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confusingly, the asterisk in `*pointer = 10` and the asterisk in `int *pointer = &a` mean two different things.

1. `*pointer = 10` Dereference the variable `pointer` and assign the value `10` to the result of the dereference operation.
2. `int *pointer = &a` Declare the variable `pointer` to be of type `int *`, and initialise it with the value `&a`. No dereference takes place here. The asterisk is here to remind you that *when* dereferencing `pointer` you *will* get an `int`. In other words, this declares `pointer` such that `*pointer` is `int`.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
int *pointer = &a;
```

is actually a shorthand, which is equivalent to this:

```
int *pointer;
pointer = &a;
```

Answer (score 1):

your question can be answered in two ways.

1. when you declare a pointer of type, say int, you do this "int *pointer" so this means you are declaring a pointer of type integer, but when you do this "int *pointer = a", this means you are initializing the pointer variable(pointer) by making it point to the address of a.

note that:-  "int *pointer = a" this does not means you are dereferencing the pointer variable, this means you are initializing the pointer variable by making it point to "&a"

2. int *pointer = &a;

   and

   int *pointer;
   pointer = &a;

means the same thing 
int *pointer = &a; this can be considered as the shortcut for writing this

int *pointer;

pointer = &a;