# Pointer behavior in Objective C vs C

Tags: objective-c

I'm working my way through Big Nerd Ranch's **Objective C Programming (2nd Edition)** and just came across this example in Chapter 15 (Objects and Memory):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date]; //currentTime points to date object at some address ("A")
NSLog(@"currentTime's value is %p.\n", currentTime);

sleep(2);

currentTime = [NSDate date]; //currentTime now points to date object at different address ("B")
NSLog(@"currentTime's value is now %p.\n", currentTime);[/code]
```

I'd like to understand why currentTime changed from address A to address B when it was assigned a new date.  Why didn't it write the data for the 2nd date into the memory location used for the 1st date (at address A)?

This c code (edit: which is embarrassingly bad but I will leave as originally-written so the comments/answers make sense):

```
int *i = 10;
i = 12;
```

doesn't change the value of &i or allocate any additional memory, so what gives?

Comment: `int *i = 10;` isn't even valid; if you declare `i` as a pointer, then `i = 12;` isn't valid either. Pointers in Objective-C behave **exactly the same** as they behave in C, since Objective-C's pointers **are** just plain C pointers. It seems that you're confusing the pointer itself with the memory it points to. When you do `currentTime = [NSDate date];`, then you are re-assigning the pointer itself, to new, freshly allocated `NSDate` object. "Why didn't it write the data for the 2nd date into the memory location used for the 1st date" – merely because you didn't dereference the pointer.

Comment: (what you are talking about would be described by something like `*currentTime = *[NSDate date];`, but that's not valid, because Objective-C objects cannot be passed around and copied by-value; only pointers to them are permitted. And it would leak the memory allocated for the new object anyway.)

Comment: Thanks.  I really need to start testing "working" code before I post it here - I'm too new to this to not make mistakes.  New question: How come you didn't write this as an answer so you can get some more rep?

Comment: this has already been discussed a thousand and one times on Stack Overflow. it's not really worth writing yet another answer, re-iterating the problem over and over again, when there have already been significantly better and more detailed answers. you'll need to search for those instead. also, do yourself a favor: don't try to jump into Objective-C until you aren't familiar with fundamental concepts of C (e. g. pointers). You will only be more confused by all the advanced(-ish) stuff like strong vs. weak pointers, method dispatch, etc. that Objective-C presents.

Comment: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5727)

Comment: `NSDate *currentTime` will create a 32/64 bit integer, which contains the memory location where the date is stored. When you assign a new date to `currentTime` you are writing a different memory location to the variable. Make sense? I find pointers are easier to understand when you learn what they technically do, instead of trying to describe them metaphorically.

Comment: *don't try to jump into Objective-C until you aren't familiar with fundamental concepts of C (e. g. pointers).*  That is a very important statement!  Objective-C is not a beginner's language -- you should understand (at least) the basic concepts of pointers and objects first.

Comment: Yes, my c pointer example was embarrassing, but I'm not sure why the question was voted down.  I think the Objective-C portion of the question is a pretty good one because it's not obvious (at least to the beginner), and @jeffamaphone's answer and example do a great job of showing exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why didn't it write the data for the 2nd date into the memory location used for the 1st date (at address A)?

You've declared `currentTime` as a pointer to an `NSDate` object, as you should.  The answer to your question lies in what `[NSDate date]` does.  It's declared in `NSDate.h` as:

```
@interface NSDate (NSDateCreation)
+ (instancetype)date;
...
```

These sorts of class methods marked as returning an `instancetype` indicate that the method is conceptually a factory method. In this case, it is shorthand for `[[NSDate alloc] init]`.  `alloc` allocates memory for a new object, and `init` initializes it.

So when you assign a new value to the `NSDate` pointer, the old object is implicitly released (since, presumably, you're using ARC and you declared `currentTime` as an implicit strong reference) and the pointer is updated to point to the newly created object.

This shouldn't be any different from the way C pointers behave.  It's analogous to:

```
CDate *currentTime = malloc(sizeof(CDate));
CDate_Initialize(currentTime);

sleep(2);

free(currentTime);
currentTime = malloc(sizeof(CDate));
CDate_Initialize(currentTime); 
...
```

Comment: Excellent - you answered the question I was trying to answer *despite* my embarassingly bad c example.  Great c example as well - I learned even more about memory handling.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**[NSDate date];** defines allocates a new address which you assign to **currentTime** assigning it second time overwrites its first value