# pointer and pointer clarification

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
void double_trouble(int *p, int y);
void trouble(int *x, int *y);

int
main(void)
{
    int x, y;
    trouble(&x, &y);
    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    return (0);
}

void
double_trouble(int *p, int y)
{
    int x;
    x = 10;
    *p = 2 * x - y;
}

void
trouble(int *x, int *y)
{
    double_trouble(x, 7);
    double_trouble(y, *x);
}
```

For the code above, I know the output of `x` and `y` should be 13 and 7.
However I'm a little confused that since it's in void, why would the value
still stored in the `x` and `y`? In other words, since

```
double_trouble(x, 7);
```

is called, why the value of `x` still 13? I mean it's void, the stored value will be deleted, won't it?

If my question is not very clear, please explain a little of function call in the

```
void trouble(int *, int *)
```

Comment: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Comment: The value of x in the trouble function is not 13. The value of x is some memory address, which contains an integer with the value 13. That integer happens to also be named x in main. This is a bad idea. It should be called xp or something like that in trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some naming confusion going on here. Once you work your way through it, you would see that everything works exactly as it should.

> I mean it's `void`, the stored value will be deleted, won't it?

There are three integer variables in play here: the `x` and `y` of `main`, and `x` of `double_trouble`. To distinguish among them, I'll refer to the first two as `m::x` and `m::y`, while the last one would be `dt::x`.

Your `trouble` function passes pointers to `m::x` and `m::y` to `double_trouble` as a pointer `p`. In the first call, `p` refers to `m::x`, so the assignment

```
*p = 2 * x - y;
```

means the same as

```
m::x = 2 * dt::x - 7;
```

with `7` coming as a parameter of `double_trouble`. Since `dt::x` has been assigned 10 before, this become an assignment `m::x = 20 - 7`, or simply `m::x = 13`.

In the second call, `y` is passed the value of `m::x`, and `p` points to `m::y`, so the same expression corresponds to this:

```
m::y = 2 * dt::x - m:x;
```

which is the same as `m::y = 20 - 13`, or `m::y = 7`.

Comment: Thx @dasblinkenlight, much clear now.
One more question, so when we call void function, only the address of pointee will be stored, and it won't be deleted?
I am pretty sure before I learn pointers, once void function is called, the value stored in void function will be deleted.

Comment: @Wii When you call a void function, any of its modifications would remain "invisible" to the outside functions, unless they are done through pointers. Modification done to a local variable or a parameter, including modifications to pointers themselves, are ignored in the caller: the values go out of scope, and become inaccessible (it's not quite right to call that "deletion", though, because nothing is done to the value itself).

Answer (score 1):

`p` points to the `x` from main, so writing something to `*p` also changes the `x` in main.

That's how pointer work and has nothing to do with the return value of the function.

your `trouble(&x, &y);` call jumps to the `trouble` function and assigns the address of the `x` from main to `x` in trouble (`x` in trouble points to `x` in main). The same happens to `y`.
So the first `double_trouble` call looks like `double_trouble( <the address of x from main>, 7);` So `p` points to `x` from main and so `*p =...` changes `x` from main.

It would be easier to explain and understand if the variables had different names.