# Compare arrays of words in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, compare, 2d

How I can compare 2d arrays of char in C?
I tried this

```
        Char **arr_1;
        Char **arr_2;

        ...// malloc. Its OK. 

        for (I=0; I<n; I++)
        {
           If (strcmp (arr_1[I],arr_2[I])==0)
                // do smth
        }
```

But it doesn't work . I'm not good in pointers.

Arrays have some array of words.

Ubuntu gcc

Without strcmp, the program works.

Thanks

Comment: `for (I=0, I<n, I++)`  --> `for (I=0; I<n; I++)`

Comment: also, did you miss to have the `{   }` to mark the scope of `for` loop?

Comment: Have u placed the null character i.e. '\0' at the end of each word or string?

Comment: "*It does not work.*" Isn't a very detailed problem description. Please be more specific. Also comparing defintly only succeeds if the data to be compared had been setup propbery. We don not know if this is the case.

Comment: Also you need to do it in nested loop, because you might need to compare each word of arr_1 with each word of arr_2

Comment: @alk ubuntu gcc compile it. But programm start and stop immediately. I dont know details (

Comment: @ Yasir Majeed I did it (

Comment: Not good at pointers? Become it.Take a look at [what are pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5754/4185106)

Comment: You might like to try debugging this yourself. To learn how to read here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must be allocating 2D dynamic array wrong.
consider this code:

```
int SIZE=5;

char **arr_1;
arr_1 = malloc(SIZE* sizeof(char *)); //initialising an array of pointers

char **arr_2;
arr_2 = malloc(SIZE* sizeof(char *)); //initialising an array of pointers

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)  
{
    printf(" Enter a name\n");  
    arr_1[i]=malloc(100*sizeof(char)); //for each pointer in this array allocate an array of characters
    scanf("%99s",arr_1[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)  
{
    printf(" Enter a name\n");  
    arr_2[i]=malloc(100*sizeof(char)); //for each pointer in this array allocate an array of characters
    scanf("%99s",arr_2[i]);
}


for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)  
{
    if(strcmp(arr_1[i],arr_2[i])==0)
   //do smthing 
}
```

Comment: I did it. Yes, for each row , and ubuntu gcc  compile it. But programm start and stop immediately.

Comment: This `scanf("%s", ...);` shall better be `scanf("%99s", ...);`

Comment: Also `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it.

```
char arr_1[10][10];
char arr_2[10][10];

int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    scanf(" %[^\n]",arr_1[i]);
    scanf(" %[^\n]",arr_2[i]);
}

for(int I=0; I<n; I++)
{
    if(strcmp (arr_1[I],arr_2[I])==0)
    {
        // do smth
    }
}
```