# Passing point as a reference in C?

Tags: c, pointers

In C, I want to pass a pointer to another function so I coded the following,

```
node* list // contains linked list of nodes

void function (node* list){

/*Whatever I do here, I want to make sure that I modify the original list, 
  not the local copy. +

  how do I pass the original pointer 'list' to this function so that I'm working  
  on the same variable? */

}
```

[EDIT]

I just like to clarify few things here,

I actually have a void function which takes a struct argument,

```
void function (struct value arg){ }
```

and in the struct, I'm defining one of my internal variables as,

```
node* list-> list;
```

so in my function, if I do something like,

```
arg->list
```

am I accessing the original list variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Comment: do you intend to delete elements in that function ?

Comment: Does your  function take a pointer or a structure? You've shown both.

Comment: `node* list // contains linked list of nodes` -- No, it doesn't *contain* a linked list. `list` is a pointer to a `node`. Presumably a `node` is a single node of a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your edit:

No, you are passing the structure by value, so the function contains a copy of the structure. If you don't `return` the structure in the function and grab it from where you called the function from, it will be lost.

Keep in mind that C does not pass by reference. It is instead simulated by passing the pointer. You could instead do this:

```
void function (struct value* arg)
{
....
}
```

And it will modify the original structure.