# Pass reference causing Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying creating a circular link list. When I try to add an element by passing the head pointer as a reference, it throws a segmentation fault. I noticed that the value of the head pointer is changing as soon as I call the Add element function.
Code snippet:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int c = 1;
typedef struct Node node;
//node *head = NULL, *temp, *temp2, *z;
node *InitQueue(node *);
node *AddQueue(node *, int);
void DelQueue();
void display(node *);

void main()
{
    int ch;
    node *head = NULL;

    do {
        printf("1.Creation Q\n");
        printf("2.Insert element to Q\n");
        printf("3.Delete element\n");
        printf("4.Display Q\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice:\n");

        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch) {
        case 1:
            head = InitQueue(&head);
            printf("%d %p\n", head->data, head->next);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("%d %p\n", head->data, head);
            int item;
            printf("Enter item\n");
            scanf("%d", &item);
            head = AddQueue(&head, item);
            break;

        case 3:
            DelQueue();
            break;

        case 4:
            display(&head);
            break;

        case 5:
            exit(0);
        }

    } while (ch != 5);

}

node *InitQueue(node * head)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("%p \n", temp);
    temp->next = temp;
    head = temp;
    printf("%p \n", head->next);
    return head;
}

node *AddQueue(node * head, int item)
{
    //InitQueue(&head);
    printf("%d %p\n", head->data, head);
    node *temp, *temp2;
    temp = head;
    temp2 = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    //printf("Enter the data: \n");
    //scanf("%d", &temp2->data);
    temp2->data = item;

    while (temp->next != head) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = temp2;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp2;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger

Comment: Please take the effort to format your code properly.  It really helps understanding what is going on (and getting good answers on SO).

Comment: there is no such thing as a reference in C

Comment: no I haven't cause I know where the issue lies but unable to come to a conclusion what is changing the head pointer even before i try adding elements to it

Comment: if you know where the issue lies - fix it. otherwise continue using the debugger

Comment: i understand that there is nothing called reference in C, but the initqueue function works fine but the not the addqueue function.

Comment: this code doesnt compile or you are ignoring warning. InitQueue takes a node * but you are passing a node ** to it (&head, head is a node *)

Comment: void main() -> int main()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're passing the actual memory address of the variable `head` to your `InitQueue` and `AddQueue` functions (*so that you can modify it inside the functions*), but they're declared as:

```
node *InitQueue(node *);
node *AddQueue(node *, int);
```

Your functions are expecting `node *` and you passed `node **`.

When you do this:

```
head = InitQueue(&head);
...
AddQueue(&head, item);
```

- 1. Types are wrong. Your compiler complained about it *and you ignored*.
- 2. `InitQueue` only worked because you're returning something.
- 3. `AddQueue` doesn't work because it's expecting a `pointer to node`, not a `pointer to pointer to node`.

You should do:

```
void InitQueue(node **head)
{
    (*head) = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (!(*head)) { /* error check */ }
    (*head)->next = (*head);
}
```

Now you call it the same way you were calling, but no need to return anything.

```
InitQueue(&head);
```

You can fix `AddQueue` by the same means.

---

### Might Interest

- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome?lq=1)
- [Pointers to Pointers](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html)

Answer (score 0):

regarding this function, as an example of how to do the operation:

```
node *InitQueue(node * head)
{
    node *temp;
    temp = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("%p \n", temp);
    temp->next = temp;
    head = temp;
    printf("%p \n", head->next);
    return head;
}
```

There are a few problems with using that to initialize a linked list with the first entry.

Suggest:

```
//node *InitQueue(node * head) // passing 'head' here is useless
node *InitQueue( int data ) // use 'data' to fill in field on first node
{
    node *temp = NULL;

    // always check the returned value from malloc 
    // to assure the operation was successful
    // if not successful, handle the error
    if( NULL == (temp = malloc(sizeof(node)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc for initial node failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    //printf("%p \n", temp);  // debug statement

    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;    // always set the 'link' to NULL so end of list can be found

    //head = temp;    // head is a copy on the stack, so has no effect on callers 'head'

    //printf("%p \n", head->next); // debug statement

    //return head;  // this is not set to point to the malloc'd node
    return temp;
}
```