# Confused about these pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is supposed to print 3,5,-1. I don't understand what is happening under-the-hood. 
What is happening when the function foo is called? I am having trouble understanding the last 4 lines in the function foo. I understand everything else.

[image]

Comment: Please post both the question, the code, what you _do_ understand and what exactly you are confused about.

Comment: Obviously the line `y++` increments the pointer, not the value where it points. You would need to make it `(*y)++`. In this exercise, they are showing the difference between pass by reference `&var` and pass by pointer `*var`. In passing a pointer, explicit dereference is needed.

Comment: "The last four lines"? You mean starting from `*y = z;`?

Comment: Oh you need explanation of the last 4 lines of `foo()`. The first line increments the local copy `z` by `2` giving it a new value `5`. The second line assigns to the memory pointed by `x` the difference by subtracting the value of local variable `z` from the value in the memory pointed by `y`. The next line increments the local pointer `y` by 1. As I have mentioned in my previous comment, you probably want to increment the value contained in the memory pointed by `y`.

Comment: [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5727/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function essentially becomes

```
foo(&x, arr[0], 3)
z = z+2 // z=3+2=5
x = *y -z; // x=arr[0]-5=4-5=-1
*y = z; //arr[0]=5
```

notice `a` is still `3` because it is passed by value. `b` points to the start of the array which is `5` after the execution of the function. and `c` is `-1` because pass by reference.