# How do read this C++ statement

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently going through C++ primer Plus by Prata and came across this statement regarding *this pointer:

```
const Stock &topval(const Stock &s) const;
```

Giving that Stock is a class and topval a function ,

**How do you read this statement?**

I tried using the clockwise/spiral approach but I get confused by all the const.
I believe that understand how to read it will allow me to better understand the concept that it is trying to prove.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a constant function taking a constant parameter by reference and returning a contant reference. `Stock const& topval(Stock const& s) const;` is probably an easier way to read it using the [right-left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html).

Comment: This is a declaration of a **member function**, right? That is, it's part of a class definition, which is part of the context for interpreting it. Don't leave out critical details like that. The question doesn't need the entire class definition, but should at least mention it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
             topval(              )        // topval is a member function...
                                    const; // In which *this is const...
                    const Stock &s         // Taking in a reference
                                           //     to a const Stock...
const Stock &                              // And returning a reference
                                           //     to a const Stock.
```

Comment: @Sabyc90 Credit to the guys over at [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) who dissect their awful one-liners this way ;)

Comment: thanks for the group link! it's easier to understand code if you can read it correctly :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a function that both takes and returns a reference to a `const` `Stock` (not necessarily the same one, to be clear), and does not mutate `this` when it does so.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` in the end is applied to the `this` pointer . The `const` in the argument is applied to the argument, and the `const` in the first part of the sentence to the return value.

simplified syntax explanation

```
Return value - function name - ( argument list ) - const modifier.
```

The const specifier is a function modifier specifying that the pointer passed to this function is const, therefore you cannot modify member variables , except those declared mutable in the class definition.

The elaborate syntax is :

```
noptr-declarator ( parameter-list ) cv(optional) ref(optional) except(optional) attr(optional) -> trailing require
```

Therefore you declare a  method That

Returns a `const` reference to a `Stock` after having received as input a `const` reference to a `Stock` object , and `this` pointer is a const pointer for this method being called.

The not so used but equivalent and arguable proper way to write this is

```
Stock const &topval( Stock const &s) const;
```

That now permits to spot where the cv-qualifier is actually applied (i.e. to the left-of the qualifier )

Comment: I think you meant _you cannot modify member variables_ didn't you?

Answer (score 1):

It declares a member function (because of the last `const`) which:

- Named `topval`
- Do not change any other member of the class, see the last `const`
- Takes only one parameter: `const Stock& s`
- Returns a value of type `const Stock&`

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a lot easier if people wrote this code sensibly:

```
const Stock& topval(const Stock& s) const;
```

`topval` is a `const` function, taking a `const Stock&` called `s`, and returning a `const Stock&`.

Simple!

Comment: that looks good also, but I'm a little bit confused about placing the & operator. Wasn't &s supposed to be a reference to a const Stock ?

Comment: @Sabyc90: No. `s` is "a reference to a `const Stock`", i.e. a `const Stock&`. It's as simple as that!

Comment: The trouble is, in a declaration like `int& x;`, the `&` binds more closely to the `x` than the `int`. For example `int& x, y;` declares `y` as an `int`, not an `int&`. So `int &x, y;` is more natural. I know what you're going to say: don't declare multiple variables in a single statement. But the language allows it, and this (I think) is what causes the confusion.

Comment: @TonyK: Oh brother. This stupid edge case rationale just won't die, will it?! Of _all_ the reasons to use the sensible, logical and semantically-correct alignment method shown in this answer, you people insist on clinging to two things: (a) the syntax _internally_ doesn't work this way, and (b) a complete edge case. How on earth could either of those two things be more important? I've literally just demonstrated with Sabyc that right-alignment is confusing as hell. _"Wasn't `&s` supposed to be a reference to a `const Stock` ?"_ No, `s` is a `const Stock&`. So write `const Stock& s`. Simple.

Comment: I thought you might blow up. That's why I made it clear that I was only trying to explain the confusion.

Comment: @TonyK: But you didn't explain the confusion. The confusion comes not from the language, but from silly people who insist on teaching the "`const Stock &s`" variant. I think that's fairly clear from the OP's remarks.

Comment: @TonyK: And, yes, I saw your "you often do". Leave out the personal attacks if you want to be taken seriously. And you wonder _why_ I'd "blow up" at you ..... which I _didn't_ ...... yeah, this conversation is already clearly not worth having.

Comment: I am not a timid person when it comes to commenting on StackOverflow. But when I see your name under a post, I hesitate -- do I really want to get shouted at again? In this case, I thought my comment was unexceptionable. But no -- I got shouted at again.

Comment: @TonyK: I did not "shout" at you?! What are you talking about?? Stop making personal insults please. Concentrate on the technical discussion at hand. It's not an "insult" just because I disagree with your comment, no matter how "unexceptionable" you think your opinion may be.

Comment: "Oh brother", "stupid", "Of _all_ the reasons", "you people" (hah!), "How on earth" -- the whole comment is loud. Surely you can see that?

Comment: @TonyK: I can't help that you've chosen to take it personally. The argument you've employed _is_ stupid. Yes, I _vehemently_ disagree with it. Strongly. That is not in any way the same as saying _you're_ stupid, which I'm sure you're not, or the same as "shouting at you". People have strong opinions. That's life. It's not the bullying you seem to be accusing me of. So relax! Have a coffee. Smile. Disagreement is the spice of life.

Comment: Don't be silly -- of course you are calling me stupid by calling my argument stupid! What else could you base your opinion of my intelligence on? But here the resolution is simply that you misread my "argument" (which was really just an observation).

Comment: @TonyK: _"of course you are calling me stupid by calling my argument stupid"_ Now _that's_ stupid. That's not true at all. And no, I didn't "misread" anything. Accusing someone of "misreading" your argument just because they don't agree with it is kinda silly. Look I'm sorry if you don't like me but, well, let's leave it there then, eh? I've tried to cheer you up but you seem intent on slandering me, so... I hope you have a nice day and feel happier soon!

Comment: "I've tried to cheer you up": reading your "Oh brother" comment again in this light has me wondering whether we are on the same planet! But don't worry, I'm not upset. I'm enjoying this as much as you are.

Comment: @TonyK: One final time, that was an exclamation of disappointment that this silly argument is still being used around the world, _not_ a personal attack!!!!!!! I thought it was pretty clear. Perhaps we _are_ on different planets?! :P

Comment: Hey @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am on your side and I agree that this stands in the way of a lot of compsci learners. What do you think are the steps we would have to take to change the language standard so that the `*` and `&` bind to the type `int` more strongly than to the variable? Is this just a simple matter of the parse order of variable (type) declaration statements? But reality sets in rapidly... It's clearly a holdover from C and cannot be changed for good backward-compatibility reasons. Maybe we can push compiler implementors to be opinionated about it and issue a warning for this.

Comment: @StevenLu: Well you'd have to redo the grammar at a fairly fundamental level. It's not going to happen. Sadly.

Answer (score -3):

```
const Stock &topval( const Stock &s) const;
```

So you're declaring a function topval, that returns the memory address for an object of the type Stock as const. The function topval takes as an argument the memory address of Stock object. Since this is const, you will not be able to change this object inside topval.

Finally const at the end means, that this function (topval) will not be able to change any members of the class Stock..

I think it's more or less this meaning, it's been a while without c++

Comment: reference is not the same as memory address. Final const means it cannot change any members of some class, not mandatory `Stock`. Which one we do not know, as we do not see full declaration.