# Type of a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

There are countless questions about pointers here on SO, and countless resources on the internet, but I still haven't been able to understand this.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2057116/4532996) quotes [A Tutorial on Pointers and Arrays in C: Chapter 3 - Pointers and Strings](http://pweb.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch3x.htm):

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

> For the moment, ignore the const. The parameter passed to `puts()` is a pointer, that is the value of a pointer (since all parameters in C are passed by value), and the value of a pointer is the address to which it points, or, simply, an address. Thus when we write `puts(strA);` as we have seen, we are passing the address of `strA[0]`.

I don't understand this, at all.

- Why does `puts()` need a *pointer* to a string constant? `puts()` doesn't modify and return its argument, just writes it to `stdout`, and then the string is discarded.
- Ignoring the *why*, how is it that `puts()`'s prototype, which explicity takes a *pointer* to a string constant, accepts a string literal, not a pointer to one? That is, why does `puts("hello world");` work when `puts()`'s prototype would indicate that `puts()` needs something more like `char hello[] = "hello world"; puts(&hello);`?
- If you give, for instance, `printf()` a *pointer* to a string constant, which is apparently what it wants, GCC will complain and your program will segfault, because:

  ```
  error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[6]’
  ```

But giving `printf()` a string constant, not a pointer to a string, works fine.

[This Programmers.SE question's answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/286226/201219) make a lot of sense to me.

Going off that question's answers,  pointers are just numbers which represent a position in memory. Numbers for memory addresses are unsigned ints, and C is written in (native) C and assembly, so pointers are simply architecture-defined `uint`s.

But this is not the case, since the compiler is very clear in its errors about how `int`, `int *` and `int **` are *not* the same. They are a pathway that eventually points to something in memory.

Why do functions that need a *pointer* accept something which is *not* a pointer, and *reject* a pointer?

---

I'm aware a "string constant" is actually an array of characters but I'm trying to simplify here.

Comment: I have read your question. It is a bit confusing for me. Can you just tell me in short what you are expecting?

Comment: @JafferWilson there, I hope I've made it clearer

Comment: You might want to read on what happens to an array when being passed to a function (in C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `puts()` need a pointer to a string constant? `puts()` doesn't modify and return its argument, just writes it to stdout, and then the string is discarded.

`puts` receives a pointer to the *first character in a string*; it will then "walk" down that string until it sees a 0 terminator.  A naive implementation would look something like this:

```
void puts( const char *ptr )
{
   while ( *ptr )        // loop until we see a 0-valued byte
     putchar( *ptr++ );  // write the current character, advance the pointer
                         // to point to the next character in the string.
   putchar( '\n' );
}
```

> Ignoring the why, how is it that `puts()`'s prototype, which explicity takes a pointer to a string constant, accepts a string literal, not a pointer to one? That is, why does `puts("hello world");` work when `puts()`'s prototype would indicate that `puts()` needs something more like `char hello[] = "hello world"; puts(&hello);`?

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

String literals are stored as arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++); thus, the string literal `"hello world"` is an expression of type "12-element array of `char`".  When you call `puts( "hello world" );`, the string literal is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, so the type of the expression is converted to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first character in the string.

> If you give, for instance, `printf()` a pointer to a string constant, which is apparently what it wants, GCC will complain and your program will segfault, because:
>
> `error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[6]’`

Remember above where I said an array expression is converted to a pointer type *except* when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators or used to initialize another array in a declaration.  Assume the declaration

```
char hello[] = "hello world";
```

Like above, the expression `"hello world"` has type 12-element array of `char`; however, because it is being used to initialize another array of `char` in a declaration, it is not converted to a pointer expression; instead, the *contents* of the string literal are copied to the `hello` array.

Similarly, if you call `printf` as follows:

```
printf( "%s", &hello );
```

then the expression `hello` is *not* converted to a pointer to `char`; instead, the type of the expression `&hello` is "pointer to *12-element array of `char`*", or `char (*)[12]`.  Since the `%s` conversion specifier expects a `char *`, you should just pass the array expression as

```
printf( "%s", hello );
```

and with string literals, just use the literal:

```
printf( "%s", "hello world" );
```

> Going off that question's answers, pointers are just numbers which represent a position in memory. Numbers for memory addresses are unsigned ints, and C is written in (native) C and assembly, so pointers are simply architecture-defined `uint`s.
>
> But this is not the case, since the compiler is very clear in its errors about how `int`, `int *` and `int **` are not the same. They are a pathway that eventually points to something in memory.

C is a (more or less) strongly-typed language; types *matter*.  Even though an `int`, `int *`, and `int **` *may* take up the same amount of space in memory<sup>1</sup>, *semantically* they are very different things and are (usually) not interchangable.  A pointer to an `int` is a distinct type from a pointer to `float`, which is a distinct type from a pointer to an array of `char`, etc.  This matters for things like pointer arithmetic; when you write

```
T *p = some_address();
p++;
```

The expression `p++` advances `p` to point to the next *object* of type `T`.  If `sizeof (T)` is 1, then `p++` advances a single byte; if `sizeof (T)` is 4, then `p++` advances 4 bytes (assuming a byte-addressed architecture, which most of us work on).

---

<sup>1. Or not.  There is no guarantee that pointers to different types have the same size or representation as each other, nor is it guaranteed that they're just unsigned integers; on a segmented architecture, they may have a more complicated *page*:*offset* representation.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The expression `"hello world"` has type `char[12]`.

In most contexts, use of an array is converted to a pointer to its first element: in the case of `"hello world"` it is converted to a pointer to the `'h'`, of type `char*`.

When using `puts("Hello world")`, the array is converted to `char*`.

Note that the conversion from array of specific size, loses the size information.

```
char array[42];
printf("size of array is %d\n", (int)sizeof array);
printf("size of pointer is %d\n", (int)sizeof &array[0]);
```

Comment: Ah, so there *is* a conversion. That makes more sense, thank you.

Comment: Yes, there is an implicit conversion. You do not need to do anything, it is always performed. The most notable exception is when the array is used as an operand to the `sizeof` operand. The other exceptions are when an array is used as the operand of the `&` (address of) operator and when used as a string literal to initialize an array object.

Answer (score 3):

`puts()` doesn't need a pointer to a string, it needs a pointer (`*`) to a character (`char`). It happens that in C, a pointer to a character (`char *`) can be assimilated to a string (an array of chars), provided that the end of the string is a null character `\0`.

Comment: Does that mean `char s[]` and `char s` are not different types, just that one happens to be a collection of pointers to `char`s?

Comment: No, `char s` is a char, not an array of chars.

Answer (score 2):

Several questions in there, but hopefully I can illustrate how pointers to pointers work.

The reason `puts` need a pointer, is that C really does not have a built in type for a string. A string is just a bunch of `char` one after another. Hence, `puts` needs a pointer to the first of the chars.

The string literal, "degrades gracefully" to a pointer. This is fancy compiler speak meaning that a string literal actually is a string of chars and is represented by a pointer to the first of the `char`s.

You need a pointer to a pointer to a type, for instance, if you want to "return" an array from a function, like so:

```
bool magic_super_function(int frob, int niz, char** imageptr /* pointer to pointer */)
{
    char* img = malloc(frob * niz * IMAGE_DEPTH);
    if (NULL == ptr) {
        return false;
    }

    *imageptr = img;

    return true;
}
```

Sometimes an example (even contrived) can illustrate a point. You would call
this function like so:

```
char* img; /* pointer to char */

if (true == magic_super_function(12, 8, &img /* pointer to pointer (to char)*/  )) {
    /* Here img is valid and allocated */
    /* Do something with img */
} else {
    /* img has no valid value here. Do not use it. */
    /* Something failed */
}
```

Comment: `puts` does not do that. `puts` returns an int representing the number of chars it wrote.

Comment: I asked about two specific functions, `printf` and `puts`, both have type `int` which is the length of the string they wrote. I do not see why they need a pointer.

Comment: @cat, what `puts` does, or does not do, is beside the point I think? :-) The above example is meant to illustrate how you can use a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @cat Those functions don't want to make a copy of the actual parameters, its call by reference to improve performance.

Comment: @cat: did you know that in C there is no `string` type? What you call a "string" is actually a *pointer* (yes!) to its first element – which is a `char`, not a `char *`.

Comment: @Jongware I knew that C does not have `string`, it has `char[]`, as I note in the question. I did not know a `char s[]` gives the address of its first element; I thought arrays aren't just a list of pointers?

Comment: @cat, the original reason for not having a string type in C was probably for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` is different from `int*` because of how it will be used in the code. You can expect to access the memory location that `int*` points to and find an integer value. This is called 'strong typing' and the language does this so that there are strict rules for how you use your variables. So even though an `int` and `int*` might both be the same size, an `int` cannot be used as a pointer.  Similarly an `int**` is a pointer to a pointer, so would have to be dereferenced twice to find the actual integer value it refers to.

In the example of `puts(const char*)` the definition of the function tells you that the function expects a memory location (pointer) to a null-terminated set of `char` values. When doing the operation, `puts` will dereference the location you give it, and print the characters found there. The `const` part tells you it won't be changing the values either so that it's safe to send a `const` array of `char` to it. When you send a literal string like `puts("hello")`, the compiler turns that into a pointer to "hello" for you as a convenience, so a pointer is still sent (not a copy of the string).

Regarding your question about `printf`, note that `char*` and `char*[6]` are different.  The first indicates a pointer to a null-terminated string, where the second is a pointer to a set of exactly six `char` values which may not be null-terminated.  The compiler complains because if `puts(&hello)` tried to treat the input parameter as a null-terminated string, it would not stop after then length of the array, and would access memory that it should not.

Answer (score 1):

int **r = 90; r is a double pointer and you are assigning 90 to the pointer. When you dereference, it will try to dereference address 0x90.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does `puts()` need a pointer to a string constant?

`puts()` is defined in such a way so that it can make use of the actual parameter instead of copying it and reusing it. Because it improves performance. Moreover it takes a `const` pointer so it can't change the content pointed by the pointer. It is ***call by reference***.

> How is it that `puts()`'s prototype, which explicitly takes a pointer to
>   a string constant, accepts a string literal, not a pointer to one?

When you pass a string literal, first the string literal is stored in read only memory and then a pointer to that memory is actually passed. So you can call `puts()` with any literal like `puts("abcd")`, `puts("xyz")`. It will work.

> `error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[6]’`

Here your are actually passing a **pointer to an array of 6 `char`s** not a `char *`. So the compiler will complain this error.