# What is the asterisk for in signal and slot connections?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

In Python Qt, I'm connecting a QListWidget signal to a slot, like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.myList, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)"), self.ListEventHandler)
```

My question is: what does the trailing asterisk in `QListWidgetItem *` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of bullet points to explain (I'll try to avoid C++ syntax):

- PyQt is a Python wrapper around Qt, which is written in C++.
- Qt provides introspection for classes inheriting from `QObject`, frequently using strings to identify things. Python has native introspection, but C++ does not.
- The syntax that you used is called ["Old-Style Signals and Slots"](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html), which uses the C++ function signatures.
- C++ has more types of variables than Python. In C++, a variable can be a value, reference, or pointer. **Pointers have an asterisk after their type name.**
- `QtCore.SIGNAL("itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)")` refers to a Qt signal called `itemClicked` that has a parameter that is a *pointer* to a `QListWidgetItem`, not the item itself.

In C++, this looks like:

```
 void itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
```

Going back to strings for introspection, to identify a signal or slot, you drop the `void`, the `;`, and the variable name (`item`), leaving:

```
 itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)
```

Wrap the above in `QtCore.SIGNAL()` and a pair of quotes and you have:

```
QtCore.SIGNAL("itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)")
```

**What is a pointer?**
There are a number of SO questions about this. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome) with a number of analogies in the answers to simplify things for you.

**If this is old-style syntax, what's new style?**
Thanks to Frodon for bringing this up. PyQt has a more "pythonic" method of connecting signals to slots, in the format:

```
object.signalName.connect(otherObject.slotName)
```

In this case:

```
self.myList.itemClicked.connect(self.ListEventHandler)
```

Read more [in the docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

Comment: Thanks, Jon! That's a very clear explanation. You've unravelled a few mysteries for me.

Comment: @PProteus For the curiosoty, here is the same line of code, but in the new-style syntax: `self.myList.itemClicked.connect(self.ListEventHandler)`

Comment: The old-style syntax is obsolete, and is no longer supported in pyqt5. You should not use it at all in new pyqt code - it's only supported in pyqt4 for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

It's C++ syntax for indicating that the function `itemClicked` is passed a pointer to a `QListWidgetItem` as its only argument.

You can think of this as being "pass by reference", rather than "pass by value".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, James, but I'm using Python, not C++.

Comment: Sure, but the signatures for PyQt signals are defined in C++ syntax unless I am completely mistaken. [This](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) certainly suggests that to be the case.