# C++ reverse automatic differentiation with graph

Tags: c++, automatic-differentiation

I'm trying to make a [reverse mode automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Reverse_accumulation) in C++.

The idea I came up with is that each variable that results of an operation on one or two other variables, is going to save the gradients in a vector.

This is the code :

```
class Var {
    private:
        double value;
        char character;
        std::vector<std::pair<double, const Var*> > children;

    public:
        Var(const double& _value=0, const char& _character='_') : value(_value), character(_character) {};
        void set_character(const char& character){ this->character = character; }

        // computes the derivative of the current object with respect to 'var'
        double gradient(Var* var) const{
            if(this==var){
                return 1.0;
            }

            double sum=0.0;
            for(auto& pair : children){
                // std::cout << "(" << this->character << " -> " <<  pair.second->character << ", " << this << " -> " << pair.second << ", weight=" << pair.first << ")" << std::endl;
                sum += pair.first*pair.second->gradient(var);
            }
            return sum;
        }

        friend Var operator+(const Var& l, const Var& r){
            Var result(l.value+r.value);
            result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(1.0, &l));
            result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(1.0, &r));
            return result;
        }

        friend Var operator*(const Var& l, const Var& r){
            Var result(l.value*r.value);
            result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(r.value, &l));
            result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(l.value, &r));
            return result;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Var& var){
            os << var.value;
            return os;
        }
};
```

I tried to run the code like this :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Var x(5,'x'), y(6,'y'), z(7,'z');

    Var k = z + x*y;
    k.set_character('k');

    std::cout << "k = " << k << std::endl;
    std::cout << "∂k/∂x = " << k.gradient(&x) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "∂k/∂y = " << k.gradient(&y) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "∂k/∂z = " << k.gradient(&z) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The computational graph that should be build is the following :

```
       x(5)   y(6)              z(7)
         \     /                 /
 ∂w/∂x=y  \   /  ∂w/∂y=x        /
           \ /                 /
          w=x*y               /
             \               /  ∂k/∂z=1
              \             /
      ∂k/∂w=1  \           /
                \_________/
                     |
                   k=w+z
```

Then, if I want to calculate `∂k/∂x` for instance, I have to multiply the gradients following the edges, and sum the result for every edge. This is done recursively by `double gradient(Var* var) const`. So I have `∂k/∂x = ∂k/∂w * ∂w/∂x + ∂k/∂z * ∂z/∂x`.

## **The problem**

If I have intermediate calculation such as `x*y` here, something goes wrong. When `std::cout` is uncommented here is the output :

```
k = 37
(k -> z, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345710, weight=1)
(k -> _, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345770, weight=1)
(_ -> x, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456b0, weight=0)
(_ -> y, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456e0, weight=5)
∂k/∂x = 0
(k -> z, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345710, weight=1)
(k -> _, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345770, weight=1)
(_ -> x, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456b0, weight=0)
(_ -> y, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456e0, weight=5)
∂k/∂y = 5
(k -> z, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345710, weight=1)
(k -> _, 0x7ffeb3345740 -> 0x7ffeb3345770, weight=1)
(_ -> x, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456b0, weight=0)
(_ -> y, 0x7ffeb3345770 -> 0x7ffeb33456e0, weight=5)
∂k/∂z = 1
```

It prints which variable is connected to which one, then their addresses, and the weight of the connection (which should be the gradient).

**The problem is** `weight=0` between `x` and the intermediate variable which holds the result of `x*y` (and which I denoted as `w` in my graph).
I have no idea why this one is zero and not the other weight connected to `y`.

Another thing I noticed, is that if you switch the lines in `operator*` like so :

```
result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(1.0, &r));
result.children.push_back(std::make_pair(1.0, &l));
```

Then it's the `y` connections which cancels.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
Var k = z + x*y;
```

Calls `operator*`, which returns a `Var` temporary, which is then used for the `r` argument to `operator+`, wherein a `pair` stores the address of the temporary.  After the line completes, `k` children include a pointer to the place the temporary *had* been, but it no longer exists.

---

While it doesn't protect against the above mistake, you can create the intended behaviour by avoiding the unnamed temporary...

```
Var xy = x * y;
xy.set_character('*');
Var k = z + xy;
k.set_character('k');
```

...with which your program produces:

```
k = 37
∂k/∂x = 6
∂k/∂y = 5
∂k/∂z = 1
```

A better fix may be to capture the children *by value*.

---

As a general tip for catching such mistakes... when your program seems to be doing something inexplicable (and/or crashing), try running it under a memory error detector such as [valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).  For your code, the report starts off with:

```
==22137== Invalid read of size 8
==22137==    at 0x1090EA: Var::gradient(Var*) const (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109109: Var::gradient(Var*) const (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x108E12: main (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==  Address 0x5b82cd0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==22137==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22137==    by 0x109FC1: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> >::deallocate(std::pair<double, Var const*>*, unsigned long) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109CDD: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::deallocate(std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> >&, std::pair<double, Var const*>*, unsigned long) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109963: std::_Vector_base<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::_M_deallocate(std::pair<double, Var const*>*, unsigned long) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x1097BC: std::_Vector_base<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::~_Vector_base() (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x1095EA: std::vector<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::~vector() (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109161: Var::~Var() (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x108D95: main (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==  Block was alloc'd at
==22137==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22137==    by 0x10A153: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x10A060: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> >&, unsigned long) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109F03: std::_Vector_base<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109A8D: void std::vector<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::_M_realloc_insert<std::pair<double, Var const*> >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<double, Var const*>*, std::vector<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > > >, std::pair<double, Var const*>&&) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x1098CF: void std::vector<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::emplace_back<std::pair<double, Var const*> >(std::pair<double, Var const*>&&) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x10973F: std::vector<std::pair<double, Var const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<double, Var const*> > >::push_back(std::pair<double, Var const*>&&) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x109520: operator*(Var const&, Var const&) (in /home/median/so/deriv)
==22137==    by 0x108D6F: main (in /home/median/so/deriv)
```

Another way to catch it can be to add logging in a destructor so you know when the object addresses mentioned in your logging are no longer valid.

Comment: I was also thinking the temporary `x*y` was destroyed, but then I wondered why its address is still pointing to something ? Because I can actually get its `children` and loop through it... If the object was really destroyed after the calculation, I should have had a *segfault* after trying to access the object, right ?

Comment: C++ doesn't try to keep track of every pointer to an object and null it out when the object's destructor runs - that would make for very inefficient programs.  Segfaults tend to happen when the memory to which the pointer points is not accessible - often because the pointer is null or never was a valid pointer; if you have a pointer to memory where an object used to be, the problem is often that the memory at that location has been released (which creates undefined behaviour /- often manifests as accessing the wrong value) rather than made inaccessible and causing a segfault.

Comment: It's long, but - judging from the upvotes - a lot of people have found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5754/410767) helpful in understanding pointer lifetimes.

Comment: I see, it makes more sense now.