# Address of a string literal and array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, string-literals

```
    int main(){
        char *str1="Hi", *str2 = "Bye";
        printf("%u,%u\n",&str1,str1);
        int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
        printf("%u,%u",arr,&arr);
    }
```

What is happening here? `str` and `&str` give different addresses and `arr` and `&arr` give same.

My understanding is that `arr` points to address of first element i.e `&arr[0]` and `&arr` will give also the same address but it is address of whole `arr[5]`. If we increment `&arr` by 1 then it will point to next element of arr[4]. But problem is that why this process is different in case of string. Please help me to visualize the concept here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C all string literals are really stored as arrays of (read-only) characters including a null-terminator. As any other array they decay to a pointer to their first element.

For `str1` in your code the compiler have generated some code similar to this:

```
// Compiler-generated array for the string
char global_array_for_Hi[] = { 'H', 'i', '\0' };

int main(void)
{
    char *str1 = global_array_for_Hi;
    ...
}
```

Your pointer variable `str1` is pointing to the first element (the `'H'`) of this array. When you print the value of `str1` that's the value you get.

When you print the value of `&str1` you get the location of the variable `str1` itself, you get a pointer to `str1` of the type `char **`.

Somewhat graphically it could be seen like

```
+-------+     +------+     +-----+-----+------+
| &str1 | --> | str1 | --> | 'H' | 'i' | '\0' |
+-------+     +------+     +-----+-----+------+
```

---

For `arr` you have an array, it decays to a pointer to its first element. When you use `arr` it's the same as `&arr[0]` (it comes from the fact that `arr[i]` is exactly equal to `*(arr + i)`). The type of `arr` (and `&arr[0]`) is `int *`.

When you use `&arr` you get a pointer to the whole array, and its type is `int (*)[5]`.

The location is same for both `&arr[0]` and `&arr`, but their types are very different.

---

On a related note, the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier `%u` is for printing values of the type `unsigned int`. To print pointers (more specifically values of type `void *`) you must use the format specifier `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: if i define str1[]="Hi" then it will behave like array that i mentioned in question?

Comment: I'm new in C. Why you / the compiler declare the char array global?

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer All literal strings are "global" and have a life-time of the full program. See e.g. [this string literal reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) for details.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude From your link _String literals are not modifiable_. A string literal like `char *str1="Hi"` isn't modifiable. In your example str1 is modifiable. Did you forget a const when declaring the array, or does the compiler handle it in a different way?

Comment: @MichaelSchäfer The thing is that the string arrays created by the compiler are not `const`. Attempting to modify one will lead to undefined behavior, and they are therefore effectively read-only (as I mentioned) but they aren't `const`. There's no way in standard C to mark an array as "non-modifiable" beyond `const`, but since they're not `const` I omitted that.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1.

```
char *str1="Hi";
printf("%u,%u\n",&str1,str1);
```

First you use the wrong conversion specifier, `%u` for both, `str1` and `&str1`, which invokes undefined behavior. For `str1` it shall be `%s` and for `&str1` it shall be `%p`:

```
char *str1="Hi";
printf("%p,%s\n",(void*) &str1, str1);
```

Explanation:

`str1` is a pointer to the address of the first element of the string literal `"Hi"`. `&str1` is the address of the pointer `str1` itself. That is the difference to the version with the array below.

---

#### 2.

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
printf("%u,%u",arr,&arr);
```

Again, the wrong conversion specifiers here. It shall be `%d` or `%i` if you want to print the first element of `arr` as `arr` is an array of `int` not `unsigned int` or `%p` if you want to print the address of the first element:

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
printf("%p,%p",(void*) arr, (void*) &arr);
```

Explanation:

`arr` (after array-to-pointer decay rule) decays to a pointer to the first element of `arr` while `&arr` is actually a pointer to the first element of `arr`. They actually evaluate to the same.

---

Note, the cast to `void*` is necessary to make the code C standard-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

`array` is not a pointer. It is contiguous chunk of memory. That the reason why `array` && `&array` have the same address.

`pointer` is a variable holding the reference to another variable. So the `pointer` gives you the reference/address held by the pointer and `&pointer` gives you the reference/address to the `pointer` itself. As the pointer is a separate 'object' you have different addresses.

Answer (score 1):

In this declaration

```
char *str1="Hi", *str2 = "Bye";
```

there are declared two local variables `str1` and `str2` with the automatic storage duration.

They are initialized by addresses of first characters of string literals that have the static storage duration.

So the value of `str1` is the address of the first character of the string literal `"Hi"`. The value of the expression `&str1`  is the address of the local variable `str1` itself.

You can imagine it the following way

```
&str1 ---> str1 ---> "Hi"
```

Arrays are contiguous extents of memory. So the address of an array itself and the address of its first element are the same. It is the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

You can imagine it the following way

```
        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
        ^
        |        
&arr----
        ^
        |
arr-----
```

Pay attention to that array designators used in expressions with rare exceptions are converted to pointers to their firs elements. So use din the call of printf the expression `arr` is equivalent to `&arr[0]`.

Regarding to your comment

> Vlad I've a doubt regard string constant, Why can't we modify this
>   char *s="HI" but we can modify this char *s[]="HI" I know about second
>   case it is simple array but can you please clear why can't i modify
>   string constant

then according to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Pay attention to this declaration

```
char *s[]="HI";
```

is invalid. There is declared an array of pointers. So to initialize it you have to write

```
char * s[] = { "HI" };
```

And you may change the elements of the array by assigning to them other string literals. That is you may change pointers themselves not the string literals pointed to by the pointers.

Comment: Vlad I've a doubt regard string constant, Why can't we modify this char *s="HI" but we can modify this char *s[]="HI" I know about second case it is simple array but can you please clear why can't i modify string constant.

Comment: @SanjayVerma See my appended answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C, constant string like "Hi, Guys" is stored on shared memory.
Consider following example:

```
str = "Hi, there";
```

The string in above code is stored contiguously. The variable `str` points to
first character of string, So character 'H' here.
So, `str` gives address of first character which stored on somewhere in memory.
`&str` gives address of variable `str` itself.

The case in array is different than above.
Array is variable(off course, const variable) that contains address of first element(that is &arr[0]) of array. And when you do `&arr` it will same as `&arr[0]`. &arr is actually address of whole array which is same as address of first element of array.

Note: print `&arr + 5` and `&arr[0] +5`, you may got some light.

Comment: Yes ravi i know about array how they behave but i was confused with str[] and *str i was thinking they both are working the same but they are different. BTW thanks for the answer.