# How does this work? Pointer to pointer assignment

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int *p1;
    p1 = new int;
    int *p2;
    p2 = new int;
    p2 = p1;    // what happens here?
    *p1=5;
    cout << "pointer 2 is " << *p2 << endl << *p1 << endl;  // both give out 5
    delete p1;  // what happens to p2 ?
    cout << "pointer 2 is " << *p2 << endl;
    delete p2;
    return 0;
}
```

What happens when I delete the pointer object p1? What is pointer p2 referencing now ? Can some one explain ? Thanks for the help

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome) helpful for understanding what pointers are. This scenario is covered under the heading "memory leak".

Comment: Important point: A pointer is a variable that happens to contain an address and can be used to access the object at that address. Other than that it's just like any other variable, so `p2 = p1;` replaces the address stored by `p2` with the address stored by `p1`.

Comment: @Brian: Thank you for the link. That explanation is a very good analogy of memory managment. It was helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is pointer p2 referencing now ?

Nothing. It's dangling. It *was* pointing to the same thing `p1` was pointing to, but you've deleted that.

Consequently, your `*p2` is broken, as is your `delete p2`; these both have undefined behaviour.

You've also leaked the second `new int`, because `p2` used to point to it but stopped doing so when you wrote `p2 = p1` (you changed it to point to the *first* `new int` instead, like `p1` does), and there's no other way to refer to it.

[image: Crude diagram of what happens in the OP's code, with respect to pointers]

Comment: Nice diagram.  I would suggest including the last `cout << *p2` statement in the fire, too

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good idea

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings my god! that was wonderful. Apparently my code has two sins.. memory leak, trying to delete a dangling object. I liked the fire part of it

Answer (score 4):

> ```cpp
> p2 = p1;    // what happens here?
> ```

You are simply copying the *value* (pointed memory address) of `p1` into `p2`.  This is no different than doing this:

```cpp
int i1, i2;
i1 = 12345;
i2 = i1;
```

However, because the *value* in question in a memory address allocated with `new`, you now have a memory leak, as you have lost your only pointer to the 2nd allocated `int` that `p2` was previously pointing at.  Now `p1` and `p2` are both pointing at the 1st `int` in memory.

> ```cpp
> cout << "pointer 2 is " << *p2 << endl << *p1 << endl;  // both give out 5
> ```

Yes, because `p1` and `p2` are pointing at the same memory address.

> ```cpp
> delete p1;  // what happens to p2 ?
> ```

Nothing happens to `p2` here, it is still pointing at the same memory address it was before.  `p1` and `p2` are independent variables, so a change to one does not affect the other.  But, the `delete` has deallocated the 1st `int` that was stored at the memory address being pointed at by `p1` and `p2`, so now they are both *dangling pointers* to invalid memory.  Since you don't use `p1` after this, that is ok for `p1`, but for `p2` the next statements:

> ```cpp
> cout << "pointer 2 is " << *p2 << endl;
> delete p2;
> ```

Will cause *Undefined Behavior*, because you are accessing invalid memory via the dangling `p2`.  The read *may* succeed in returning stale data that is still present at the memory address, or it *may* return garbage, or it *may* crash.  The `delete` will almost certainly crash, since the memory has already been freed earlier, but that is not guaranteed either.  *Undefined Behaivor* is just that - **undefined** - so literally anything could happen.

Comment: Thank you the detailed explanation of the what went wrong especially trying to access object that p2 is pointing to. This was the error message I got while executing the program : "free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted". I understand now what happended.