# visualization of pointers in memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Being a beginner in C, I was aware that pointers are a special data type used to store the address of a data type. If I calculate size of any pointer in my PC (64-bit OS) it's 8 bytes.

In memory representation each address represents 1 byte (byte-addressing... I read it on Wikipedia), so it means that a pointer will occupy 8 contiguous blocks of memory just like an integer does (4 bytes)?
And if we print the address that the pointer stores; will it be the base address of those 8 bytes?

Comment: No, it isn't the address where the pointer is stored; it is the address where something *else* is stored.

Comment: ... and "the base address of those 8 bytes" is a "pointer to a pointer".

Comment: @WeatherVane, I can't understand, can you please explain briefly.

Comment: A pointer points to an object. The pointer is itself an object, so a pointer to a pointer means "a pointer to another pointer".  A pointer is the *address* of something, an analogy is say your home address. If you write that address down and place it in a cupboard, and then tell your friend where the cupboard is, they have a pointer to a pointer. You might like to read SO's [What are the barriers to understanding pointers and what can be done to overcome them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome)

Comment: @WeatherVane, I now understand; thank you but what is the sense of size of pointer being 8 bytes?

Comment: So that the 64-bit compiler can access the 64-bit (virtual) address space. With a 32-bit compiler you can only access a 32-bit memory space, even if the computer has a 64-bit address space.

Answer (score 0):

For visualizing data in your program, you might wanna check out [DDD (Data Display Debugger)](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), in case you're lucky enough to use Linux, not Windows.

But since all that you're asking is how pointers work and how are they structured in memory… well… short answer is "that depends", because it depends on the particular machine architecture you're on, the compiler etc. If you're on x86-64, then yes, pointers are just 8 subsequent bytes (64 bits), little-endian ordered (that is, from the least-significant byte at lower memory addresses up to the most-significant byte at higher memory addresses), which are supposed to be interpreted as an unsigned integer where each subsequent bit is a binary digit for the subsequent powers of two.

Those bits, when interpreted as an unsigned integer, are supposed to indicate a memory address of something else, of a particular type (the type associated with the pointer). The pointer points at the address of the first byte of that object in memory, i.e. where the object begins. How many subsequent bytes does the object take depends on the type associated with the pointer.

Here's how it might look like in memory:

```
                    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F           
00000001'0020000x: (38 00 20 00 01 00 00 00) 55 23 0A 25 00 43 2F 10
00000001'0020001x:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000001'0020002x:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000001'0020003x:  13 37 D0 0C 00 00 00 00 [02 B0 AD 1B EF BE AD DE
00000001'0020004x:  1A 00 0F F0 0D D0 01 C0] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The address 0x00000001'00200000 contains a pointer to a struct of two 64-bit integers (I marked its memory area with round parentheses). The first byte of it is 38 (the least-significant one), then 00, 20, 00 again, 01, and three more 00s (the last one being the most-significant byte), so they represent the number 0x00000001'00200038, which is the address of where the object pointed to starts in memory. There are some more bytes after the pointer, but they're irrelevant, they are part of some other data.

Now let's look what's at the address contained in the pointer: 0x00000001'00200038. The first byte of this region is 02, then B0, the next one is AD, then 1B, and so on…  There's supposed to be two 64-bit integers packed in a struct, so the object pointed at is 16 bytes long (I marked its memory area with square brackets). The first integers is 0xDEADBEEF1BADB002, and the second one is 0xC001D00DF00F001A.

In other words, we have the following situation:

```
typedef struct {
   int first, second;
} TwoInts;

TwoInts *ptr;

TwoInts obj = { 0xC001D00DF00F001A, 0xDEADBEEF1BADB002 };

…

ptr = &obj;
```

The object `obj` has been allocated in memory starting from the address 0x00000001'00200038, while the pointer `ptr` has been allocated in memory starting from the address 0x00000001'00200000, and it contains the address of the first byte of `obj`. Like this:

```
 ptr:                       obj:
 0x00000001'00200000:       0x00000001'00200038: 0x00000001'00200040: 
(0x00000001'00200038)----->[0xC001D00DF00F001A] [0xDEADBEEF1BADB002]
```

Also keep in mind that when it comes to memory addresses on x86-64, they're in virtual memory address space, which means that they're not exactly the addresses of things in actual physical memory on your RAM chips. There's an address translation going on inside the CPU's Memory Management Unit which translates the addresses from virtual address space into physical addresses in RAM. When the operating system loads your program and starts running it as a process, it allocates some memory pages for it and sets up a mapping from the virtual address space to the physical memory. So from your program's point of view, it's as if you had the entire address space from 0 up to 2^64–1 available to you, but most of this address space maps to nothing and cannot be read from or written to by your program because they're not backed up by any actual memory. There are some segments of memory that the operating system allocated for your process and mapped to actual RAM that you can use, and that you can read from or write to safely. If you try to access some memory outside of that range, the CPU will detect it, raise an exception, and tell the operating system to slap you and terminate your program for misbehaving :J
Also, you can run several instances of your program, all of them seemingly using the same memory addresses, but since they are "virtual", each of them might actually be mapped to a different physical address so that the instances didn't overwrite each other's data. It's as if each of the instances had its own memory cell with an address 0x00000001'00200038, or as if each instance has been run alone in memory, having its entire address space for its own perusal.